# How to measure the quality of a user's answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality

I'd like to generate a [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) query which makes a reasonable ranking of users by the **average quality** of their answers.

Reputation is heavily influenced by quantity.  As [Jeff points out](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/quantity-always-trumps-quality.html), quantity is essential — but even in his story, quantity was a means to an end; the end being quality.

Other than having a large enough sample size (50-100 questions minimum for a user to be included), I'd like to get a basic idea of **reputation excluding the quantity factor**.

What factors, and potentially algorithm, are good indicators of **total average quality**?

My rough, first ideas:

- Median answer score
- Top answer percentage
- Accepted answer percentage

Comment: I suspect that the biggest complicating factor you'll meet is the different activity levels in various tags.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's definitely a "quality" algorithm in use on Stack Exchange sites already, aswe already have a tool to be able to review "low quality posts" and they have an associated quality score.  Perhaps without giving up too much of the secret sauce, they could expound upon it?

**edit**:  Related - [Heuristics for detecting a bad answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)

Though it's not just that "not bad" answers are good, there are other qualities that make an answer good that aren't just the inverse of qualities that make an answer bad.

Comment: It's not just 10k (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), but I would guess that "quality score" is only calibrated for the low end of the spectrum (it mostly picks up short answers).

Comment: Indeed, like @Renesis says, the [heuristics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers/84669#84669) are only shown for low quality posts.

Comment: @arjan but in this case "low quality" and "short length" are the same. The heuristic doesn't even attempt to classify posts > (n) chars.