# How do I write a comment to a question or a answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Give new users some indication that comments exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87582/give-new-users-some-indication-that-comments-exist)

Hi,
I don't find the place/link/... where I can write a comment on a question or an answer...

I now found out that 50 points are needed... but before I wrote this question I didn't find the right answer using the search...

Maybe the user interface needs more usability at this point? e.g. the button is visible but grayed out, and tooltip answers the mystery...

Thanks! 
  Stefan

BTW: Yes, bad usability is a bug...

Comment: I had the same feeling when starting to use SO. I searched everywhere where should I click to post a comment to an answer and nothing, until I found out about the 50 points.

Comment: don't think that's an exact duplicate. I know that comments can be done (I see them from others) but I don't know how.