# Problem in Posting answers

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I was unable post new answers:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account.

I was posting links to my blog, not knowing that it's not allowed.  I will make sure not to repeat the same mistake again.

So what should I do to be able to post answers again?

Comment: What happens when you try to post an answer? What error message do you get?

Comment: A quick examination of the answers that you've given reveals that posting links to your blog is not the *only* problem. All of your answers are of terrible quality, all but useless to anyone who reads them.

Comment: if it is "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account" the please see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Comment: @tombull89, then the OP could not have posted this (now migrated) question on SO either... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - doh! that'll teach me to assume.

Comment: what error do you get when you post an answer?

Comment: @Cody to be fair though, while I can't judge on the code's quality because I don't speak the language, looking at form, diction and originality of the content (I can find no plagiarism), I've seen much worse.

Comment: Hrm, the existence of worse answers doesn't really do much to convince me that *these* answers are worth having on the site. Maybe my standards are too high, but I don't think so. And in looking more closely at the answers, I see that **most** of them have already had the signature links removed by other users, who also took the time to leave a comment or an edit explanation. It's pretty hard to claim ignorance here. The site notifies you when you get a comment and when your post gets edited. You should start seeing a trend...

Comment: @Cody good points.

Comment: See i m srry for such ingorance..I just didn't noticed those..
I cant comment more than that....see like this site and i want to make some contribution to the socity so y i m telling, will make sure next time wont happen the same..

Comment: I Cant try more than this to make someone to beleive me...and its the mistake i was doing by accident...
I am trying to put answers frm last 3 days,i thought the problem might be resolved..but its not...
I cant ask more than a single chance from U

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot post answers to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 5):

Yoor answers have triggered a mechanism that protects against "bad" answers. If you think this is in error. Contact team@stackoverflow.com.

Repeatedly posting signatures is a hint. So please also take some time to read and understand the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Any details? Such automatic rejection is not described in [How does Stack Overflow attempt to prevent low-quality questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers/84669#84669)

Comment: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account.
This is the error i m getting whenever i try to post new answers..

see initially i was unaware about some facts in stack overlfow, like advertising of our personal websites are prohibited..

I will make sure that from next time to not do so.