# Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)
>   [Cannot post answers to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow)

I'm sort of new to SE and I'd like to **answer** for this question: [list.onItenClickListner is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305410/list-onitenclicklistner-is-not-being-called)
Unfortunately I can't post my answer because it says:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

The specified link is wrong since that site discusses when somebody can't post a **question**.

I checked several SE topics about it but found no solution.

[Cannot post answers to StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow) - I'm not aware of being banned from the site so I believe I should be able to post anwers.

[My profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675462/papaiatis) - as you can see I'm still a newbie with 2 questions and 1 answers. I don't have any deleted questions or answers. On 6th July, I could answer for an android related question. Now I couldn't.

Please kindly help me in this situation because I would like to participate and not spam the system at all.

I know there are similar topic about my question out there but none of them helped me or gave me useful information. I spent two hours on this already.

Comment: `I don't have any deleted questions or answers.` I sure hope for you that that claim is true.

Comment: I'm not aware of having a deleted question. I checked my profile page and it doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: On another note: Do you have any other user accounts or are you sharing your internet connection? At least the question-ban is lower then account-level.

Comment: I don't have another account but I am at work so yes, I'm sharing the same internet connection with other colleagues. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Could be (if one of your colleagues wrote crappy answers), only way to be sure is to wait for diamond or developer to come along and have a look. And you're sure none of your answers were deleted? I mean, you only wrote one? Would save us a lot of work (read: close as duplicate and move on) if you'd tell us now.

Comment: I joined to Stack Overflow 5 months ago, I asked a question regarding to Facebook development and that's all I could remember..

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you do have deleted answers -- many of them, with warnings from a moderator on one of them.

So everything is working as designed here.

Comment: Many deleted questions? I would remember them. I do believe you but it seems my account was used by someone else too. I have no doubt that the system works as expected.

Can we continue this in private to find a solution for it?

Comment: @papaiatis - Read the answer again. "you do have deleted **answers**". Nothing about *questions* there,

Comment: @ChrisF - You're right. It's **answers**.