# Why are other users allowed to answer a question but not me?

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot post answers to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow)

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451217) shortly after it was posted, and thought I had a pretty good answer, so I attempted to post it.  However, when I do that I get the message:  "Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."

When I look up that page, it makes it sound as if whatever is blocking me is aimed at those who post questions that are not of a nature that stackoverflow is looking for.  Yet others have been able to post answers to this same question. The ironic thing is that in this particular case my answer is more concise and portable than the others already posted.

Comment: Have you rapidly deleted a lot of answers in recent times?  Had any answers marked as spam?  There is something in your answering history that has tripped the alert.

Comment: That message has nothing to do with *that particular* question or *that particular* answer you are trying to post. It has to do with your history of questions/answers.

Comment: @Andrew his history seems to look quite okay, though. Maybe an IP mixup?

Comment: @Pekka Maybe, but a lot of times the posts have been deleted

Comment: I don't believe I've ever deleted an answer, nor should any of my answers have ever qualified as spam.  I have had moderators convert a couple of my answers to comments that I wanted to make comments in the first place but couldn't because I didn't have a high enough rating to do that.  The explanation at the link above makes it sound as if I should only see this message when trying to post a question, not an answer, and in fact it suggests posting some quality answers as a way out of this status.  Catch-22!

Comment: This is definitely worth looking into. If nothing happens here, send an E-Mail to `team@stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: One more upvote on SO and you get to comment -- but note that if you can't comment, it's by design :P

Comment: 3/7 answers (now 8) were deleted as non-answers. I don't know what exact ratio would trigger it, but that has to be a factor.

Comment: At least two of your answers were on your own questions. This is normally considered fine, but with so few questions and answers perhaps that too plays some role in the metrics used to determine answer quality?