# How to recover after asking one bad question

Tags: support, specific-question, post-ban

The question is here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861448/best-way-to-build-a-fluid-html-css-page/16861543?noredirect=1#16861543

I edited to correct the wording and make it clearer. But I have to say, I am really stunned to be banned from asking questions just after 1 bad question. I think this is quite extreme, but that is outside the scope of this message.

I edited the question for clarity. **What else can i do to be able to ask questions again?**

Comment: And you don't have any other downvoted (and deleted) questions?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I read the documentation and it says clearly that 1) you need multiple bad questions to be banned, which was not my case (thus said solution does not apply to my case). And 2) I changed the wording of my question but it had absolutely no impact, ban still here, and downvotes still here. The answer to what we can do in this case needs an update or clarification.

Comment: Well, there you go (see George's answer). Hence a perfect dupe. Participate in ways still possible and gain rep in the process. That's all and all of it is explained in the dupe.

Comment: Bart, i only have 2 questions. Ever. And the other question was not deleted or downvoted. I have no other deleted question, I really was banned for one bad question. (That wasn't as bad in my opinion, it might have needed clarification which i did but nothing that deserves such drastic measures.)

Comment: Well, it seems you have asked at least 3, not 2. One heavily downvoted. 1 deleted. And the other one doesn't add much to weigh against it. If that is all, the ban might not be very deep. The advice in the duplicate (and yes, it's a dupe) still holds.

Comment: I like how one person down voted this question, and went and downvoted my other questions I talk about here. Some people try very hard to mean for the sake of it.

Comment: -4 Now, great. It probably won't stop there. I think this site tries to avoid the "youtube comment" syndrome by filtering questions, but instead of manifesting in the questions people now channel their need for trolling into their downvoting now it seems.

Comment: That's a bit of an unfortunate side-effect of Meta. If you bring your questions to the attention of the community, attention you will get. And that might result in votes (up or down). I tend to stay away from it when brought up via Meta, but users are free to vote however they see fit.

Comment: Please contact us using the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page; we'll help you work this out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, there are three bad questions:

- [What are some recent Web programming good practices and Standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846252/what-are-some-recent-web-programming-good-practices-and-standards)
- [Why Won't these 2 columns align?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873380/why-these-2-columns-wont-align)
- [Best Way to Build a Fluid HTML and CSS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861448/best-way-to-build-a-fluid-html-css-page/16861543?noredirect=1#16861543)

What makes these 'bad' questions?

For *What are some recent Web programming good practices and standards*, it's the textbook definition of Not Constructive. You ask:

> Now I am back into development and i want to play catch up. What did i miss?

How would that help other developers?  Is that something that can be searched for on Google?  I'm guessing you thought Stack Overflow was a discussion forum when you posted this, and then it was closed and deleted and you realized that we're not a forum.

For *Why won't these 2 columns align*:

This isn't an awful question, but it's not a really searchable question either.  Trimming down some non necessary HTML and CSS would help it be a better question, but this could use a title makeover in order to be upvoted. Maybe something like?

> How do I align two columns using CSS?*

*test title, I didn't actually look to see if this is what you are asking

For *Best way to build a fluid HTML and CSS page*:

You're once again diving into 'not constructive' territory.  The 'best way' is the clue that maybe the question should be focused better.  What's best for me is not necessarily best for you. How can we have a definitive answer to 'best'?

Once again, a title change could help your issue, because you're really asking:

> How do I build an HTML file so I can change the place where different elements of the page appear simply by switching CSS files?

That's a good question; but we need some sample HTML and CSS to go off of, which you don't provide.  It's still open ended, but with the right mixture of HTML, CSS and what you're trying to achieve, it could become focused enough to be answerable.

Comment: Now, where was that feature request to see your own deleted questions in your profile, again... ;)

Comment: @J.Steen - With these links the OP can see their deleted questions.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I know. I was being snarky! Perhaps a little unnecessarily. What I was implying, was, that if that feature was in place then you wouldn't have to ask a mod for the links. Not that it's a lot of trouble, but still. I like doing things by myself first and only asking for help when I absolutely have to.

Comment: @Oded I also realised my comment wasn't at all clear. I fail. Keep up the good work!

Comment: What makes the second question bad? It didn't get any bad votes and it was very specific!

Comment: @Draken It's at least not great, in the sense that it doesn't provide any counterbalance against your other negatively evaluated questions. If you can improve it, do so.

Comment: @Oded I think we'd stop these meta questions if we could let question banned users see their deleted posts in their profile.  Granted, we'd get all new ones, but I'm getting a little tired of having to link people to their posts every single time they're question banned.

Comment: @Draken I initially just posted the three links; I wanted to get the answer in before it was closed as a duplicate.  I then edited the answer with my thought process behind that. If you look at the edit now, it should show you the reasons why.

Comment: I am concerned that it takes only three questions to get question-banned.

Comment: Putting links in the profile would provide quick access, but it wouldn't provide the sort of guidance and analysis you've added to them here, unless that already existed in comments on the questions themselves.

Comment: @George Stocker I understand now the reasons and I will edit my questions properly according to what you explained. Thanks for your help! And I still this isn't a duplicate, only this topic lists my deleted questions (which i forgot about, it was a long ago) and explains to me why MY questions were not as well asked as I thought. Thanks again George.

Comment: @AlEverett When they're really bad questions (downvoted, deleted, closed), I'm not.  I just wish we would show users these questions in their profile; as well as giving a message why the question was deleted (deleted by the community, for help in getting your question undeleted, see this help center post, or something like that).

Comment: @AlEverett, seems to me that three questions from someone with zero answers is a reasonable point to ban at.  It's a question AND answer site, after all ;)  I hope that people who have some answers (and some upvotes from those) would have a lot longer leash.

Comment: The comments on that deleted question make me sad.

Comment: @Shog9 Wow. Those are really bad comments.  I hate new features for the sake of new features, but is there any way we can introduce deletion reasons? That way the community has a broad consensus of when something should be deleted (not all closed things deserve to be deleted) and 2) People whose content is deleted at least have a stock reason why it was deleted.

Comment: Question bans are supposed to be for people with a **pattern** of bad questions. I just don't think three is enough to establish a pattern. Five, maybe. I'm not pushing to change it (goodness knows SO has more than enough questions coming in) but I'm surprised it's that low.

Comment: It's not a hard limit, @Al. The number of down-votes, etc. also factors in. A couple of these... really got hammered.

Comment: Fair enough. (Can't see. Need points.)

Comment: @George - I don't think we need delete reasons.  If you're so damn oblivious and ask a question so fundamentally terrible that it gets deleted, then I don't think tacking on a canned reason will help one bit.

Comment: @Shog - honestly I'd say that deleted question got the comments it deserved.  Barbarians at the gate, and such...

Comment: @AdamRackis It sounds as though you should have skipped the Corn Flakes this morning.  They may have been contaminated.  Golly.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - I'm happy and mellow, coding from home with some good music on :)  I just have little patience for people who come and post crap with little regard for SO's standards

Comment: @AdamRackis I think the problem is, we're not doing a good enough job helping users who haven't posted questions understand that we are not a forum, and the normal rules people have learned over the *x* number of years they've been on the internet don't work here.  We're trying, with the Help center, and "How to Ask", but we keep running into that age-old chestnut: *People do not read.*

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If "people do not read" is it still up to us to solve that? Up to a certain point, yes, but you can only take that so far.

Comment: @Bart, George, Shog - we can't solve the problem of users not reading, but [we can easily do more than we currently are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123026/warn-users-before-their-account-is-suspended).  This OP above strikes me as the type of user who may very well have read the warning if we threw a huge fire-engine-red banner in his face

Comment: @AdamRackis I agree. I also think we should let people see their deleted content. Because we hide it from them, we encourage these questions that don't have to happen.

Comment: @AdamRackis I have no objection to that. However, it starts to feel a bit like *"Oh, I'm sorry officer, did I drive too fast? Wasn't I allowed to drive that fast? Can't you just give me a warning?"*. Especially if you see the crap ton of information users are already provided with. But yeah, if it helps the situation it would have my vote.