# Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account. (Note: ANSWERS, not questions)

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot post answers to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow)

I am fairly new to the site. I posted a few answers (about 4 or 5) that were all similar to each other. This is because a new library had emerged that provided a new solution to all of the questions. This has seemed to have earned me an absolute ban on answering questions!? I looked up the issue here on meta, but could only find information about being banned from asking questions, not providing answers.

Also, the link provided took me to a meta post explaining a question-asking ban, not an answer-giving ban.

It is too bad because I am not trying to spam or game the system at all, just trying to participate. If anybody knows what I can do to go about reversing the ban, let me know.

Comment: Duplicate of [Cannot post answers to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow) and [Problem in Posting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89802/problem-in-posting-answers). Did you follow the link that was supplied by the alert?

Comment: Um... All of your answers were flagged as spam and deleted. Perhaps that has something to do with it? 

Nothing wrong with linking to a library if doing so answers the question, but if that's *all* you're doing it's... gonna looks suspicious.

Comment: The link went to the question-asking ban, not the answer-giving ban. Thanks for the links, I had searched for the exact text of the error and found only the question-ban results.

Comment: I can't blame you for not finding those, as looking on the Related Questions list to the right shows some... hilarious results. That said, as pointed out by those, the points in the link are pretty much the same between questions and answers. Perhaps we need to update its terminology a bit, though.

Comment: Thanks, Shog9. The questions were all "How do I render SVGs in Android?", and I believed that a very suitable answer was that new library. I also provided some additional information based on my experience in using the library. Anyway, life goes on.

Comment: @Shog9: The answers are pretty benign and, I daresay, useful. Can the ban be lifted?

Comment: @Robert: have you tried clearing the flags?

Comment: @Shog9: That option is greyed out on the answers.

Comment: @Robert: Undeleting should do the trick then; @pents90, can you give it another try?

Comment: @pents90: Since I deleted these answers without allowing them to go through the complete spam delete cycle, I've given you the benefit of the doubt and undeleted them all, giving them each an upvote so that they have a zero score.  We'll see how the community responds to that.

Comment: Hey, you might want to edit your answers to make them relevant to each question, and so they aren't all exactly the same.  Also, you might want to add a note stating that you're a user of the project and not affiliated with it otherwise.

Comment: Hello, I've also just got banned for a similar reason. I wouldn't mind knowing why, or how to get this ban reversed. I am a legitamate contributor to StackOverflow and my answers are always helpful, constructive and to the point. However, I linked to two external libraries (one which I have developed, another I have not) in multiple posts and now my account is suspended. Big shame really! I'm trying to get started on SO and to do so, an easy way is to post on the many similar questions answers that you know well.