# Account blocked from answering questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

In an attempt to honestly answer a question, the heuristics flagged my account, and I can't answer questions anymore. What gives? I'm completely altruistic in my posts. There's nothing spammy at all.

Comment: Is this your profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/538921/florida-seo ? If yes then I can't see any banned user notice on your profile.

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: @Harry: Don't forget that anything objectionable may have already been deleted, so looking at a current list of answers may not be meaningful.

Comment: I attempted to answer the question on this page ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195791/javascript-incrementing-a-variable

However I was given the following message when I submitted my code ...

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    * Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Comment: @Harry@Sathya@Gabe ...

I have the answer to the problem #http://stackoverflow.com/users/536129/elgoog needed ... I'm just trying to give the solution to his problem ...

Comment: Please review your profile.  Are all the answers that you've posted still present?

Comment: Have you deleted any questions or answers, or have any of your questions or answers been deleted?

Comment: @Michael: Your link contains "If you tripped the heuristic by just a tiny bit, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again." -- how would it make sense to write quality answers if answers were blocked as well as questions?

Comment: @Gabe: ...write quality questions?

Comment: @Michael: Are you saying that somebody who routinely gives poor answers can get blocked from writing further answers until they ask some quality questions? Somehow I doubt that's the case.

Comment: @Gabe: Can you explain why you doubt that? Writing quality *questions* can take different skills than writing quality *answers*, and I wouldn't be surprised if SO devs recognized that.

Comment: @Michael: You may right, but I'd expect to have heard about such a policy somewhere if it was the case.

Comment: @Gabe - Yes, really. See the last line of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers/84669#84669) to [How does Stack Overflow attempt to prevent low-quality questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers/).

Comment: @Dori: I wasn't doubting the existence of a "bad answer" ban; I was doubting that asking questions would be an intended way to lift the ban.

Comment: @Gabe - Can't hurt to try it, I figure—I haven't seen or heard of anything saying that when you're blocked from answering, you're also auto-blocked from posting questions.

Comment: Well, now that you got upvote on one of your answers try again there's good chance the block is removed.

Comment: Ugh, can you please remove "SEO" from your name?  It makes me feel all ooky in the tummy.

Answer (score 2):

You currently show as having two answers on your account—one from December and one from about two hours ago.

However, in February, you answered a question, and that answer included a sig that linked to your site. Enough people viewed it and flagged it as spam that your answer was auto-deleted.

Given that you were able to post an answer a couple of hours ago, my *guess* is that the system sees you as borderline. Neither of your answers have ever received an upvote, and when combined with the spam flags, leads it to doubt that you add quality content to the site.

What to do? As others have said, while [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this) is about questions, not answers, it does offer some advice.

Comment: What advice does it offer? Write some quality answers? Or plead your case in an email and hope you're not ignored?

Comment: Wow ... thanks for the info Dori ... This is a lot more involved than i expected ... :-)

Comment: @Gabe - the other choices were [Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account. (Note: ANSWERS, not questions)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91693/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account-note-answers-not), [Cannot post answers to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851/cannot-post-answers-to-stack-overflow), and/or [Problem in Posting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89802/problem-in-posting-answers) — but they didn't appear to be terribly helpful, either.

Comment: .. Maybe I did add a link ... Honestly I don't remember ... However, I don't quite understand how I answered another question shortly before this issue my account was blocked and did receive a vote ...