# I'm a moderator dealing with a user asking a question in an answer, what do I do?

Tags: support, asking-questions, moderators, moderator-abilities, moderator-faq

In the moderator queue I see a lot of `not an answer` flags.  Mostly, these are users (mostly new ones) writing questions as answers.  How can I best handle this when it's a *good* question?

I want to leave a comment, but deleting the answer also removes the comment and item from their inbox.  The way I'm doing this now is leaving a comment for a few hours (so hopefully the user sees it), then deleting the question.

Is there a better way to handle this, and communicate to the user how to ask a question on my site?

Comment: What about converting it to a comment? (I probably should have made this an answer, just for the irony.)

Comment: @Justin - moderators can do that already :)

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting it. :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It *used* to be that, when you deleted a post, the comments were also removed from the author's inbox. That was a problem if one of the comments was from a moderator to explain why the post was a removed; It simply disappeared.

So we changed that behavior.

**A moderator's comments now stay in the user's inbox,** even if the post is deleted. But for the comment to remain in the inbox, **a few criteria have to be met:**

1. The comment has to be left by the moderator deleting the post.
2. The comment has to be to the author of the post (not a [@reply to another user](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)).
3. The post has to be deleted within one hour of leaving the comment.

### How This Works

So if a user posts a question as an answer — despite [all the warnings we have in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers) — here's how it would look:

Friendly community moderator Nick Craver sees a flag about an answer which should have been posted as another question:

[image: post in the queue]

He decides it's worth his time, as it's a decent question posted as an answer. So he comments on that post to educate the user:

[image: comment by moderator]

And then **immediately** deletes the post:

[image: deleted post - moderator view]

Normally comments are deleted from the inbox when the post is deleted. But *now* the user will **still** have the moderator's message in their inbox:

[image: the user's inbox after deletion]

When they visit the link from that inbox item, they'll see my comment and the FAQ link automatically added to their post:

[image]

That faq link on the deleted answer (this is not a new feature) points to [the deletion section of the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) so the user can see common reasons why deletions happen:

[image]

**Please note this behavior is specific to moderator comments only!**

Comment: Thank you! I've been wanting this for a while.

Comment: Also, no moderator should be without [Pro-Forma Comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments) (unless you have a valid excuse like a poor excuse for a browser).

Comment: Why is this specific to moderators? As an ordinary user, when I see a non-answer with a worthwhile question, I leave a comment like this and flag `not an answer`. But my comment is only useful if the poster comes back before the answer is deleted, which feels like I'm wasting my time. I gather I shouldn't leave such comments then, but why burden moderators with them instead?

Comment: @mmyers Personally, I prefer to handwrite all of my comments.

Comment: Does this feature only work for deleting answers, or does it also work for deleting questions?

Comment: @Willie - both meet the criteria here, so it'll work for either, though new users won't have permission to see the posts

Comment: "Though new users won't have permission to see the posts." Okay, that answers my question and what would've been a follow-up. Thanks.

Comment: I thought <10k users couldn't see their deleted posts? If they can't how do they get to see the fullpost + comment and *Why was your post deleted...* info?

Comment: @Kev - users can see their own deleted *answers*, not questions.