# Can we have a 'Last 24 Hours' tab in the moderator tools?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Since we hand the torch from time zone to time zone several times a day, a tab labeled 'Last 24 Hours' might be a good idea. Information on this tab might include:

- A summary of and links to moderator messages sent in the last 24 hours
- Notes from devs and community coordinators (perhaps pinned from chat) in the last 24 hours, discussing the tools or guidelines
- Notes from other site moderators (perhaps from chat) in the last 24 hours, which might be as simple as "Keep an eye on [link], it's getting heated" (anything directed at `[foo]mods:`, ordered by pinning and stars?)
- Summarized, aggregate data from the stats area letting us know how busy the site has been that day. Did certain posts become 'viral' ?
- A list of 'movers and shakers' on the appropriate meta site

This would be a great starting point for moderators who sit down to start their 'moderator time' and a great help in handing off the proverbial torch.

We can get all of this by going several places, my hope is that it wouldn't be difficult to give a simple overview with links in a different tab.

Time, of course would be server time.

#### As an addendum:

I do visit chat on a regular basis. I read the SO blog on a regular basis. I do click all of the tabs eventually, but when I sit down to do what I said I would do - I typically dive right into flags. Did I miss something neat [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96342/im-a-moderator-dealing-with-a-user-asking-a-question-in-an-answer-what-do-i-do/96343#96343)?

I'd really love a tab that lets me get caught up without going to a bunch of other tabs, or other places - just so I can be sure I'm up to speed.

Comment: The "day" tab is particularly usefulness for just this reason, it rarely has the content I want to see since for me it's reset an an awkward time. 24 hours would be way more useful when doing content reviews.

Comment: Colour commentary on things of note and memes dropped in chat would be fun.

Comment: You have lots of great feature requests with no answers. This makes me kind of sad. +1

Comment: User annotations would be a perfect thing to show - certainly you can see them if you look at profile pages every time something comes up, but knowing about the recent ones up front would be way more useful.