# Could we get a "yesterday" view in the Moderator Tools Admin Summary?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a 'Last 24 Hours' tab in the moderator tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97970/can-we-have-a-last-24-hours-tab-in-the-moderator-tools)

I know we have a "day" view already, but everything gets reset to zero at 4 PM my time, making the stats more or less useless after that time until some activity gets built up.

It would be nice if I could see what everyone did yesterday, while the new stats accumulate.

Note: Similar to, but not quite the same as [this,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97970) my feature request should be relatively easy to implement, requiring only a new SQL WHERE clause, an additional click div, and perhaps another controller method.

Comment: Both are going the route of presenting a snapshot of mod actions done yesterday, or the last whenever to allow for quick grounding/catch up

Comment: My request is much more specific and smaller in scope, but oh well...