# Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, auto-delete

A couple weeks ago, I asked for help: [How can we stop premature deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171763/how-can-we-stop-premature-deletion)

And I got some *fantastic* responses. A big thanks to everyone who participated in that discussion - *you're* the reason I don't completely hate Meta Stack Overflow.

The big takeaways from that discussion were:

- **Show users their deleted content.** By far the most common response, and understandably so: without this, it's *always* a trade-off between cleaning up trash and letting the asker know what they did wrong.
- **Delay deletion.** There were a few different takes on this, including "pending deletion" votes that would only take effect after a period of time had passed, and straight-up blocking normal deletion votes for a period of time with spam/offensive flags and moderators able to take care of the worst stuff in the interim.
- **Improved oversight for deletion.**

That last item gets into an area we'll have to discuss in depth later on, namely: stuff that shouldn't be deleted *at all*. It's important - but it'll have to wait a little bit longer.

Joel, Jaydles, Robert & I met last week to discuss the first two and "quick deletion" in general. Here are three short-term changes we'd like to make:

### 1. Authors should see their deleted questions (if they have a link)

This doesn't go quite as far as [this old feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), but it does solve the most fundamental problem: if I have my question open when it's deleted and refresh the page, I'm not presented with a 404. It would also make *support* easier in some cases - [for instance, automatic deletion of abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173194/auto-deletion-a-bit-trigger-happy).

Note that the primary rationale given for declining the old feature-request - authors able to undelete their own content - was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/can-the-owner-of-a-question-get-it-undeleted-with-his-vote-alone-and-also-could) a while ago; the concerns over making deleted stuff permanently visible in your profile are still somewhat valid, however.

### 2. Restrict quick deletions on anything asked "in good faith"

This wouldn't even *have* to be a system-enforced restriction, although that's probably a good idea. The idea is simple: don't delete any question that isn't blatantly abusive.

- Spam? Kill it.
- Gibberish? Erase it.
- Rants? Banish them.
- A too-localized, vague or overly-broad programming question? Meh. Just close it and move on.

If we did have to restrict deletion, it helps that there are already *flags* that cover most of the really bad stuff... Flags that automatically delete once a sufficient number accumulate on a post. But that still leaves a lot of rubbish laying around, so we'd also want to...

### 3. Automatically delete closed and abandoned questions after a short period of time

It's hard to ask folks who already feel they're drowning in an ocean of filth to hold their breath a little longer. I think [mog said it best](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers/171179#171179):

> I'm getting burnt out on playing janitor

I've felt that way. There's not much of a reward in helping to moderate Stack Overflow. No one compliments you when you close an off-topic question, or even notices when you delete a terrible one. You hold out some hope that if you keep at it, the site will keep being something you enjoy - and maybe that the folks whose writing you enjoy will keep enjoying it as well. But you know in your heart that it's a treadmill to oblivion; with the volume of questions Stack Overflow gets every day, even closing the bad ones is hard - keeping up with deletion is proving to be impossible:

[image: closed questions by week]

Now, it's a bit unrealistic to say that *every* closed question should be deleted, [even when that's the recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete); still, there are currently 48 thousand closed questions on Stack Overflow that have no up-voted or accepted answers, score <= 0, haven't been edited since they were closed, and don't have any pending re-open votes...

If we deleted those automatically, that would cover 70% of the questions deleted *manually* in the last month, and 73% of questions deleted within 2 days of being closed. Forget delayed deletion - for the majority of questions, **no one would need to bother deleting them at all**.

[Automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) already accounts for the vast bulk of all questions deleted. Why not just expand that to handle the stuff we can be fairly certain won't ever be revived? Abandoned questions, already evaluated by the community and closed, with no recent activity to indicate any interest in re-opening them.

Right now, automatic deletion only kicks in for questions over 30 days old. I think we could drop that considerably - say, to 7 days - and get rid of *more* cruft, faster and with less effort than we're doing now by hand.

We haven't settled on a concrete criteria for what "closed and abandoned" should mean yet. Here are some ideas - look 'em over & see what you think:

- [Closed, no answers, and no activity for at least a week](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104931/closed-no-answers-and-no-activity-for-a-week?deadline=7) (32K)
- [Closed, no up-voted/accepted answers and no pending reopen votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104933/closed-no-up-voted-accepted-answers-and-no-pending-reopen-votes?deadline=7) (61K)
- [Closed, no upvoted or accepted answers, scoring <= 0, no reopen votes, no edits since closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104939/closed-no-upvoted-or-accepted-answers-scoring-0-no-reopen-votes-no-edits-s?deadline=7) (48K)

The goal is to capture anything that's contributing nothing to the site *now*, and shows no signs of any effort by anyone to correct the deficiencies that are preventing it from being a useful question. I think if we get this right, then we can afford to look at manual deletion - by moderators *or* high-rep users - as more of an exception-handling task and stop mixing the time-sensitive deletion of overtly abusive posts with the convenience of just voting to delete as soon as a question - any question - is closed.

Comment: You employees are getting a whole lot more verbose. Are you paid by the word now?

Comment: Whatever the reason, it's certainly *not* subconscious desire to put readers to sleep before they get to the punchline. I *guarantee* it.

Comment: __Closed should not be just about creating a path for deletion.__

Comment: @LanceRoberts: It isn't, but there's really no point in keeping questions around that have no hope of rehabilitation.

Comment: Unless you're going to improve every single question that gets closed, then that's not entirely true @LanceRoberts Either way, they're not advocating deleting good content, so I don't see what your issue with the proposal is

Comment: I agree that there are plenty of closed questions that could be deleted, but it's a subset, not the whole.

Comment: For example, a question was deleted today that had a good Eric Lippert answer, gone forever now.

Comment: Are you then proposing to restrict the 20k+ ability to delete immediately? I know it can be abused but it's really useful on ocassion.

Comment: So long as the roomba doesn't achieve [self-awareness](http://twitter.com/selfawareroomba)...

Comment: @ben: If automated deletion takes of the lion's share of deletions, the remaining use cases where something really needs to get deleted can probably be handled adequately with moderator flags.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485701/using-double-quote-in-string/15485887#15485887)? It's the most recent deleted Eric Lippert answer.

Comment: It's a good answer, but not a legendary one, and certainly not epic enough to warrant preservation of such a highly localized question.

Comment: @mmeyers, I'm only 9k on SO, so I can't see it yet.  Robert is right that is wasn't legendary, but I thought it was good, so no reason to delete the question which I had flagged to change to a 'too localized' close reason from NARQ.  Makes me not want to flag for close reason changes again.

Comment: Does your graph use the DatePosted or the DateClosed/DateDeleted? If its the first, it may be skewed a bit because older posts have had a much longer period of time to accumulate delete votes. I noticed this discrepancy when I was writing queries to look at [Close trends for Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3140/1130), and the [two](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/104978#graph) [graphs](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/104977#graph) look quite a bit different.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: The question I linked had no flags and was closed as TL, so it couldn't be the one you're thinking of. But before that, Eric Lippert hadn't had an answer deleted since August. And the only flag I see in your recent history about close reasons was on a rather poor PHP question. I'm not saying that things don't sometimes get deleted too easily ([far from it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes)), but maybe a better example is in order.

Comment: It's creation date, @Rachel - that said, you'll notice that I cut it off about three months ago; as you say, the skew is pretty noticeable otherwise: once you hit mid-February, you start to see the effect of the *existing* automatic deletion: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OsQOy.png

Comment: If you do allow users to view deleted questions if they have the link, will you be leaving comments from deleted posts in their Inbox or on the Responses tab in their profile? I know there have been times when I open/close my inbox without clicking on a message (usually because I clicked on a different notification, or clicked too fast and closed it by accident), and then when I open it again the comment on the deleted post is gone

Comment: Currently behaves this way for comments left by *moderators* immediately prior to deletion. Might be worth expanding that, but not as part of this change - the whole point is to try and slow down the deletion of active stuff to where it's not *necessary* under normal circumstances (moderator deletion can often be quick for various legit reasons, hence the allowance for pre-deletion comment notifications). @Rachel

Comment: Wait, about the "closed and abandoned" part - doesn't closing a question force it to become de facto abadoned? It's awfully hard to have your question become de-abandoned if there's **no way for anyone to answer it**. :/

Comment: +1: Bravo! And I definitely welcome the day when you implement "Improved oversight for deletion." I've definitely seen people abuse their delete vote privileges.

Comment: @James: you can still edit closed questions and vote on them (including voting to re-open). But yeah, a good many closed questions *are* abandoned.

Comment: I have seen a few questions in the close review queue that should be closed, does not have an up vote, but does have a very useful link in a comment.   The questions asker has thanked the person that left the comment, but can’t up vote it as it is a comment.

Comment: When a question is closed as a duplicate but it gets views from Google, it is still useful as it point people to the questions that has the answers.

Comment: Duplicates are excluded from this, @Ian. They can be removed via other "abandoned question" scripts, but those tend to be predicated even more heavily on "no one is using this" criteria.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The following changes are live now:

- Deleted questions will be visible to their authors, regardless of those authors' reputation.  They won't be *linked to* anywhere<sup>†</sup> that they're not already linked, but if someone knows where to find their question and it's been deleted, they should always be able to view it.
- Delete-voting within two days of closing is disabled on questions scoring -2 or above, regardless of the voter's reputation.
- Automatic deletion of closed, abandoned questions for questions meeting the following criteria:

  - Closed more than 9 days ago
  - Not closed as a duplicate
  - Score <= 0
  - Not locked
  - No answers with a score > 0
  - No accepted answer
  - No pending reopen votes
  - No edits in the past 9 days

For recent examples of the sorts of questions that will be deleted, you can [view results from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109914/closed-scoring-0-no-accepted-answers-or-answers-scoring-0-no-reopen-votes?deadline=9).

<sup>†</sup> Linking from the profile was added in June 2013, [under some conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492).

Comment: Awesome, just one thing: maybe exclude the user's own vote in "Delete-voting within two days is disabled on questions scoring -2 or above"? User who want to delete will downvote anyway.

Comment: Will users get inbox pings about comments on deleted questions? IIRC the system with deleted answers differentiates on the basis of the mod-status of the commenter.

Comment: questions work the same way, @manis

Comment: I think we should enable pings for comments on deleted posts (if they're not already enabled). Sometimes a user beats me to leaving an appropriate comment, and it's annoying to have to type it out again just so I know they'll see it it and not be left to wonder where their question/answer went.

Comment: The second point is downright brainless. Bad stupid questions with no effort put in them/which make no sense/whatever, need to be destroyed.

Comment: @H2CO3: It's those sorts of questions that should have -2 or worse, which makes them candidates for deletion under this new scheme.

Comment: @Matt Not enough. The site is already much more cluttered with noise like these "questions" than it would be acceptable... and now developers are pulling moderation tools out of the hands of users?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: if that was true, I don't think H2CO3 would be complaining so loudly. The idea here is to restrict speedy deletion on posts that might have *some* redeeming value, even if it's not enough to ultimately salvage the post. Posts that were asked in good faith, even if they're off-topic or duplicates or whatever, those can remain long enough for the asker to maybe learn something from the experience, but if a post gets heavily down-voted and then deleted, so be it.

Comment: @H2CO3: Good news: you're not the only one with high quality standards around here. (Reinforcing Matt's point in his comment.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I know, fortunately... :) I'm just a bit scared that the number of unwanted posts will rise, but if you don't think that's the case, then I accept that too.

Comment: If author can see own deleted questions, why don't we show it in his profile? (i.e. in to [questions tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9?tab=questions))

Comment: @hims056 If that is the case, [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) would be status-completed. Jeff must be very disappointed to see this happen as he is still alive. (He actually edited his comment to remove the part that could lead to a potential assassination, maybe things have changed?)

Comment: If someone comments on a post and it gets deleted before the author sees the comment, will they still get notified of the comment and have the link to the post in their inbox to view the comments? I have seen posts get closed, commented upon as to why it was closed, and community-deleted all before the OP has had a chance to see what's happened to their post (their "last seen" time in their profile was before the comments/closure).

Comment: "The following changes are live now: Deleted questions will be visible to their authors". You sure about that? (I'm not seeing http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39538 for example.)

Comment: @msh210: None of this applies to Area51, which isn't really a Q&A site (it's based on a very old version of the SE codebase, but there are * significant* changes to how it works). Most of it should apply to [Area 51 Discussions](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: @hims056: no one (except for mods and devs) sees deleted posts listed in profile questions and answers lists. That's been true for 10K users (who can see all deleted content) for years, no reason to change it for this.

Comment: @Rachel: notification rules are unchanged at present. This does make [moderator pre-deletion comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164295/moderator-deletion-comments-on-questions-are-fairly-useless) on questions more useful, since until now folks with < 10K could only read the first 90-100 characters of the comment in their inbox. Folks who aren't moderators are restricted in their ability to quickly delete questions, with the intent of providing authors a chance to be notified and informed of the discussion prior to deletion.

Comment: @Shog9 The restriction in only being able to delete after the post has been closed for 2 days only applies to posts with a score of >= -2 though. For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16175888/302677) came up [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9114912#9114912) yesterday which resulted in it getting swiftly deleted. Many times the community is quick to delete highly downvoted questions, even if the OP hasn't had a chance to login and view the comments explaining  why the post is bad and what needs to be done to fix it. This doesn't teach the OP anything

Comment: @Rachel: Which comments there do you think should've notified the author? FWIW, he likely *did* see the first one...

Comment: @Shog9 Probably the first one which explains why the question is bad, and possibly the 3rd one pointing out another major flaw in the post. Then 2nd also contained a hint towards the OP's answer too. And showing the OP the close reason would have been useful too. I saw the question had 2 delete votes yesterday, and the user's last seen time was the same time the question got posted. User has only existed for two days, but he/she has been "last seen" 21 min ago. That's just an example though. I've come across many other rapid community deletions that occur shortly after closing.

Comment: Will a zero-score self-accept exclude a post from deletion?  I'm not sure that's desirable (user posts a terrible question, it is closed and downvoted, user posts an equally unhelpful answer like, "never mind, I fixed it on my own", and accepts that answer, excluding the post from automatic deletion).

Comment: Only from *automatic* deletion, @jadarnel27.

Comment: Oh, right.  That is what I meant.  I don't think that's desirable.  If the user has accepted their own answer (zero-score), and the question is downvoted, I don't think the justifications for exclusion apply (the question has been closed out / abandoned, and is very unlikely to be improved upon ).

Comment: This is not a particularly common scenario, @jadarnel27. If it becomes a problem, we can probably add an exception fairly easily though.

Comment: Fair enough, no sense in fixing a nonexistent problem.  Thanks for checking!

Comment: @Shog9 just noticed that while I can see my deleted question just fine with less than 10K rep, I can't edit it. Is this on purpose? If so, worth mentioning this in this post.

Comment: @Sha: you can if you have [edit rights](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) on the site. Editing deleted questions is a little bit dodgy, since they don't get bumped - but since this is primarily for informational purposes, I don't think this restriction is a problem.

Comment: @Shog9 but isn't improving your deleted question then flagging for undelete one of the goals here?

Comment: The primary goal was just providing the information on *why* it was deleted more than offering a path to undeletion - we'll see if this becomes an issue for support, but I tend to doubt that it will (very few people do this even when they have the ability to do so).

Comment: @Shog9: *"...no one...sees deleted posts listed in profile questions and answers lists. That's been true for 10K users...for years, no reason to change it for this."* Yes, there is: >10k users are much less likely to have questions deleted than new users. New users should see **why** their question was deleted, with comments. That's the whole point of showing them. They're not going to magically know they need to bookmark it. They may do that, but there is a very strong reason indeed for listing deleted questions in their list of questions (only when they're looking at it).

Comment: It seems like if you want people to learn and ask better questions, you should let them know if their questions were deleted so they can go back and try and improve.  All the current system does is frustrate and confuse low rep people like myself (and I speak from experience)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: not magic; there are rules for notifying folks about comments, and a fair number of support requests involving folks returning to questions they'd asked without assistance. I'm open to expanding the scenarios where folks get links to deleted questions, but only when there's a good reason for them to be returning to those questions. For instance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179106/make-users-pass-a-review-assessment-as-final-stage-before-question-ban

Comment: You have... No deleted questions, @Jock.

Comment: @Shog9: Perhaps you've never heard of the "many paths" rule of UI design. Not helping new users in the ways we can, including giving them links to their deleted questions, just begs for more bad questions for no good reason. Harm in not letting them find them? They keep repeating mistakes. Harm in letting them find them? ________________ It's not even a hard call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the goal is to provide as many paths as possible for folks to learn from their mistakes, starting *well* before the question is deleted. Comments, close reasons, edits and even down-votes can all provide routes to instruction for those willing to follow them. It's rare (and should be still more rare in the future) for a question to be deleted before its author has been given a chance to learn from it. The ability to view deleted questions adds yet another path, but pointing users to it should be the rare exception, not the rule.

Comment: @Shog9: Question: If a brand-new user asks a question and disappears (as frequently happens), comments are posted to it, the question is closed, and the question is deleted; then the user comes back to SO (not having kept a link to the question). Do they see those comments in their inbox, and do those inbox notifications take them to the deleted question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: if they disappear for *days*, then there's a good chance they won't see anything when they return.

Comment: @Shog9: What if they come back, say, two hours after the question is deleted? Do the links in the inbox take them to the question?

Comment: @Shog9 according to [this comment by Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179391/can-no-longer-ask-question-on-stackoverflow?noredirect=1#comment542800_179391) on a now deleted question, 10K users **can** see deleted questions listed on the profile. So what's the truth? (For <10K the comment says *We don't list them, however, unless you are +10k*)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: 10K users do see deleted questions listed in a few places (Favorites come to mind), but not in their profile's questions list (this would be considered a bug if it happened, and was considered a bug when it did happen briefly a few months ago).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: right now, comment notifications only persist past deletion for moderator comments left prior to moderator deletion. We might tweak this to allow other sorts of notifications to persist if there's a clear use-case for it (for instance, on *answers* the canned review comments notify authors post-deletion). Right now, the goal is to reduce the number of deletions that happen within a short time of closure, which side-steps this *and* a bunch of other problems.

Comment: @Shog9 fair enough, was thinking Oded meant in the questions list. Favorites and Bounties tabs are the two places I know of. By the way, users with less then 10K shouldn't see deleted post linked anywhere? If so, I'll submit bug report with details.

Comment: Generally-speaking, users with < 10K should only see links to deleted content when it's something they can see *and would need to see* for some reason. These are pretty rare; feel free to report anything you see that strikes you as odd. @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @Shog9 will do!

Comment: @Shog9: If the comment notifications don't persist, and there's no link to the question on the person's profile, then letting them see the question if they bookmarked it is pretty much useless and, frankly, half-a***ed. If the goal is to improve the quality of the questions and answers on the SE network, it's perfectly obvious that people posting substandard questions should be able to see why those questions were deemed substandard. Hiding that information from them is, to put it charitably, self-defeating.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I think you're making a mistake in thinking that the majority - or even a sizable minority - of the folks asking crap questions are willing to put *any* effort into learning from their mistakes. I'll go a long way to help anyone who contacts us about getting q-banned, but the truth is that most folks who repeatedly ask bad questions aren't interested in changing that. Show a bit of effort, get a lot of help - but let's not waste our limited energies on folks who will trample them.

Comment: @Shog9: I think you're making the mistake of failing to see just how frustrated and turned off people are if they post a question, then come back and it's just gone. Again, and I can't say this enough: There is ***no harm*** in making it possible for them to readily find those questions (for instance, via their profile, or via comment links in their inbox). There is ***very real and clear harm*** not doing so. And if you're not bothered about those people, why make the half-change that's been made? It makes no sense.

Comment: The change as it stands solves the immediate problem of helping folks who do come back looking for something they've asked, wondering why it was removed, @T.J.Crowder. It also enables us to do other things in the future (expanded comment notifications for instance), but for now it just makes things a lot easier for the folks who *do* care enough to go looking for their questions.

Comment: @Shog9: *"The change as it stands solves the immediate problem of helping folks who do come back looking for something they've asked, wondering why it was removed"* No, it doesn't, except in the edge case where they've bothered to bookmark it. I don't bookmark questions I ask, I expect to be able to navigate there. Again: What. Is. The. Harm. In. Listing. These. For. Them. ?! Why this three-years-and-running obstinance to doing such a simple and obvious thing? Why keep them in the dark? Why actively hide information from them?

Comment: No, it's also helpful if they remember their browser keeps a history, or ask about it here on Meta, or email us. But yeah, what's the harm in giving folks a permanent list of everything bad they've ever done? At best, it's demoralizing... at worst, it generates a huge amount of angst from folks who wouldn't have bothered otherwise. There are around 700 questions deleted every day on SO, most of them crap that stands zero chance of being restored; do you really want to do that much hand-holding every day? 'Cause I sure don't. You can't save them all, @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: @Shog9: So give them a chance to dismiss the items from the list. (Delete the deletion, if you will.) That's exactly zero justification for not giving them the useful feedback in the first place. I don't expect the questions will be restored. I expect that (some people, the people we actually want participating on SE) will learn what is and isn't useful. Example: My first post on SO, I made an a** of myself with a signature line. But I saw the feedback, and learned from it. If my answer had just been deleted with no explanation and no way to find it, would I have contributed as I have? No.

Comment: They get useful feedback. *Prior to deletion*. We're working on improving that feedback, but we can't do anything about folks who aren't willing to listen other than get them out of our hair. Go look in the 10K tools, at recently-deleted posts @T.J.Crowder: right now, there's a pile of questions posted by someone in the span of about an hour, all of which were closed and commented on and resulted in... Another crappy duplicate. Do you really think we should devote more development resources so that he can go back now and read the feedback he ignored the first 6 times?

Comment: @Shog9: I think you're cherry-picking. SE has devoted development resources to *dramatically* less useful things than the incredibly simple matter of letting a user see their own deleted posts (particularly questions). Like the phenomenal, time-wasting idiocy of policing use of the `@`. Seriously, if it would take more than 10 minutes of dev time (`(DELETED = 0 OR USERID = ?))`, you need to revisit your development procedure. I won't keep going on about it, I think I've made my point, and the SE management can listen or not, your prerogative.

Comment: Of course I'm cherry-picking, @T.J.Crowder: I'd much prefer to focus on the folks who're doing something good or are willing to learn to do so. You used your own example - well, it didn't take a half-dozen deleted questions for you to figure out how to get along, did it? Or even *one?* The cost of the feature itself is trivial - the cost of supporting it, decidedly non-trivial... And for what benefit? For *whose* benefit? Not yours or anyone in your position; not even mine, although I have a *far* higher crap to good ratio than you do. So who does this benefit *really?*

Comment: @Shog9: I'm not seeing any significant increase in support requirements allowing people to see their deleted questions. Who benefits? Well of course, the occasional person asking a bad question who *will* pay attention to why it was deleted benefits.  But guess what? So do **I**. So do you. Do does everyone who uses SO. Why? Because people like me, who avoid voting to delete questions until we think the questioner has seen why, can freely vote to delete bad questions proactively. Look at the feedback the [SE management are getting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645) on this.

Comment: Read [jon's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/124697#124697) to that question. That's pretty much what we're aiming for here.

Comment: @Shog - it seems to me the logical solution here is to hide deleted questions *by default*, but allow users to show them *if desired*.  I have to agree with TJ here, that the harm is virtually zero, and it quite likely could help some people.  And I can't imagine this would take much development effort.  At all.

Comment: @Shog9: I understand that. I just strongly disagree with it. But I don't see much point in continuing this discussion. I am quite certain the current policy is, by my way of thinking, not just wrong but *very* wrong. I don't see that changing. I also get the impression that I'm not going to change *your* mind. So it's probably best to leave it.

Comment: @Shog9: Sorry, having said that, I realized I never finished my thought above about inbox notifications: If their inbox notifications still took them to the question a significant time after the question was deleted, that would come near serving the purpose I want to serve (making it easy for those who are willing to learn, to learn). Perhaps ensuring that's the case would be a mid-point? It also addresses the "rub their noses in it" point, because of course once you've seen the notification, it goes away. (Might be useful to put a note on the question telling them it's not linked elsewhere.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: can you flesh that out and post it as a separate feature-request? This is getting *long*... Oh, read this first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133729/treat-comments-on-deleted-posts-from-moderating-users-like-comments-from-diamond

Comment: @Shog9: Sure, no worries. To help with that, a couple of quick questions: 1. I've read through the linked feature request. Is it in fact the case that only the canned comments notify the OP on deleted questions? So if I leave a comment before voting to close, the user doesn't see that in their inbox (currently)? 2. You said above that if someone came back "days later," they might never get inbox notifications. What are the boundaries on that? 3. Is there a "Your question was deleted" inbox notification? (It's been a long time since I was a new user...) :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: canned comments on *answers* notify authors, even if their questions are deleted. There are no canned comments for questions... *yet.* Comments from moderators posted shortly before a post is deleted will notify the author, even if their questions are deleted. No other comments can be relied on to produce an inbox notification once the post is deleted. There's no "deleted" inbox notification. My comment about "days later" was simply that a closed question becomes much more likely to be deleted after a few days.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks, that's what I needed to know. And I assume there is no "your question was deleted" notification... I'll write up a feature request.

Comment: You changed to 9 days just because of your nick?

Comment: Well, there was some concern about making the period *exactly* a week that... I can *kinda* see... at least on smaller sites. 9 just makes it easier to remember @Sha

Comment: Can self accepts not count?

Answer (score 26):

I think you should tighten the automatic deletion, using all three bullet points you outlined above, and show people their deleted questions (if they have a link).

I've long thought that automatic deletion could help immensely with this problem if the time frames were shortened, and keeping the deletions out of the user's profile (until they get to 10K rep) would alleviate most of the "whining" that Jeff Atwood so eloquently talks about.

It would also give the mods true "comment and delete" ability, instead of this "almost, but not quite" ability that they have now.

Comment: _"comment and delete" ability_ - do you mean, as in [Allow diamond moderators to comment on deleted or locked items](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158439/165773) feature request?

Comment: @gnat No, I guess Robert meant posting a comment explaining what's wrong ("This question is aweful. Deleting it.") and then hitting *delete*. With the OP seeing what the issue was and what happened since they can still view deleted questions.

Comment: @slhck you mean, somehow making mod comments reach / notify the targeted user? (as of now, comment notification gets _abducted by aliens_ if commented post is deleted)

Comment: @gnat Yes, that'd be a solution for this problem, if the user can see the deleted post.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that users [still don't get notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-a-stack-exchange-notification-when-a-question-gets-closed) when their questions are closed. I think we should at least give users a notification so that they will have a chance to improve their questions before they are deleted.

Answer (score 17):

If system-assisted early deletion is the tradeoff for removing the early delete votes of 20k users, I can get behind that. I'd probably be most comfortable with the third of your options, although I honestly couldn't find anything as an example worth saving even in your second option's query.

I'm a big fan of the [change in closed question wording to emphasize editing questions into shape](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-help-us-improve-closing-verbiage) and [better explanations for why questions were closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv), but we have to help that out by making sure that questions which could possibly be redeemed live long to have a chance. Removing 20k early deletion votes is one way to keep some of these alive longer, and you can feel safe that bad questions you forget to return to can be caught by the safety net. Really terrible stuff can still be flagged (like it usually is today) and moderators can remove those exceptional cases earlier.

One request I would have is to change the wording on the page people get when visiting a deleted question. Currently, that page reads (to <10k users):

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of
>   moderation. Please refer to the FAQ for [possible explanations why a
>   question might be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion).

This makes it seem like every deleted question was removed by moderators. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166229/what-role-should-the-market-or-community-have-in-deciding-if-questions-are-c) is an example of the kind of misunderstanding that can occur as a result. Now, in that case the ability for someone to see their own deleted question would have prevented that part of the problem. Still, I think the wording here could be improved for other outside visitors (or those who answered a now-deleted question), particularly if the system is going to be deleting more of these for us.

Comment: +1 on revising the removed question text.

Answer (score 16):

As a mod, more automatic deleting greatly lessens two of my biggest concerns as a mod:

#### Getting rid of crap

Having closed, clearly low quality content on the front page is embarrassing. So is having it on the first page of /questions. But when do I manually delete it? A day is too soon. After two days I'm likely to forget. But at the moment, that crap's unlikely to be automatically deleted unless it's answerless, downvoted and closed. Closed I can almost always count on, downvoted, usually, answerless not as often. But the 30 day wait is killer.

#### Having the community do deletions

This is practically impossible on certain early-mid beta sites or recently graduated sites where there just aren't many users with the delete privilege. I feel like I should let the community make these decisions moreso than me, but it just...doesn't happen. Sometimes it *can't* happen. But if we don't require high levels of coordination between vanishingly rare top-rep-tier users, this problem goes away.

I'd feel a lot better knowing this junk will, for the most part, handle itself. There's clear paths to *keeping* the content as well (just edit/fix/reopen/upvote it) so I'm not concerned with the baby being thrown out with the bathwater. At least not a baby no one upvoted, who wants that baby. No one.

Now aside from that, I have one concern: I'm not sure an accepted, unupvoted answer should keep a post around. Off topic questions often get an off topic but correct answer or a "you actually answered my question! I give you this checkmark" accept. Keeping those around doesn't help anyone and it only takes the OP to prevent a deletion. In my opinion, someone else should have to indicate that the answer is useful before we start keeping around the question forever.

Comment: your concern looks reasonable - _accepted answers immunity_ feels indeed slippery to me. As explained in [hotness formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/165773) post, "accepted answers are a fine social contract, but **not a good data point for question or answer quality**" - meaning it doesn't really indicate a valuable content. I can imagine this as sort of protection for new users who might need time to get rep for upvote privilege, fine - but even then, I can't see how keeping zero-score, _unattended_ answers is justified for more than, say, a year

Comment: Yeah, bad questions with bad answers are still bad questions.  "can I have a dollar.", should be deleted  as offtopic not answered with "no"

Answer (score 8):

**The plan of attack you outline sounds great.** I assume the work you have done recently to mark duplicates differently than regular closed questions will factor into the auto-deletion routine, but make sure duplicates closed under the old system get distinctive treatment too :)

The most applicable bit I see for smaller sites is the ability for OP's to see their own questions if they have a link. This is particularly meaningful in that they will get an inbox ping or two with comments from a mod if something is manually deleted. Auto-deletion might be silent and they might not have a link to follow, but if there is something they need to read then they would have the link.

**Let that Roomba roll!**

Comment: Yeah, I'm ignoring duplicates for this discussion (and in the example queries I wrote) - while *some* duplicates are worth deleting, that's probably not something that should be done automatically.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a big fan of automatic deletions because there's no oversight, and no warning to the user that their post went missing.

But if you did increase the automatic deletion window to items older than 7 days instead of 30, I'd like to see the posts be:

- closed

  - as something other than duplicate
  - over 7 days ago so the user has time to see the closure reason
- no answers

  - something answered is much more likely to have the OP coming back to the post to re-read the answer
  - the answerer may come looking for their answer so they can copy parts of it into another answer (I do this all the time)
- no upvotes

  - if a post got rep, users are likely to come looking on meta for their missing rep when the post gets deleted, thus increasing moderator workload instead of decreasing it
- no reopen votes in the past 14 or 30 days

  - if someone made an attempt to reopen something, it was probably valuable to them in some way, so give the post a larger window of to stay visible before deleting it
- no activity for at least a week

  - no one is trying to fix or reopen the post

The whole point of automatic deletions is to reduce the moderator workload, and it wouldn't make sense to have the process trigger a lot of "Where did my question/reputation/answer go" posts appearing on meta as a result of the change. You want to be sure you only get rid of posts that are no longer useful to both the community and the OP.

With that said, there are many posts which are not useful to the community and could probably be deleted, but that are useful to the OP (mostly localized posts). If you had some way for the OP to see their deleted posts from either their profile or from some non-publicized url path, then I would be much more in favor of looser automatic deletion requirements.

I've personally had multiple occasions where I've gone to look for an answer I got in the past, only to discover I'm unable to find the post in my profile anywhere because it's been deleted. Sure the question wasn't useful to the community and I could understand the deletion, but the answers that were posted were still very useful to me.

And last of all, on your point of

```
Restrict quick deletions on anything asked "in good faith"
```

Here's my problem with that: not every user sees a post the same way.

- One person's version of "spam" may be another person's version of "answering questions", particularly when someone is trying to publicize their personal blog.
- One person's version of "gibberish" may just be another non-english speaker's version of "trying to get answers"
- One person's version of "rant" is another person's version of "asking a question"

In all cases, deleting content as soon as it's closed does not teach the user anything.

You have a whole army of community users who are happy to help out with site maintenance, however most of the time they are looking at recently active posts, and not older posts that have been closed for a bit.

If you provided this large group of users with a way to say "delete this post in X days unless it gets significantly edited or reopened", then you will have many more users stepping up to help out with site maintenance, thus reducing the moderator workload.

Answer (score 5):

I like this. On sites like Physics, the community doesn't participate much in deletions (and we don't have enough active high reps anyway). As a mod, I *could* do it, but none of us have really felt the need for it. This seems to solve the problem.

However, come to think of it, do we really *need* to *delete* the posts? The point is to avoid the broken windows problem. Instead of deleting them (making them unsearchable and unreadable), here's a radical idea:

Just make them hard to get to.

Basically, any 7 day old closed post will be hard to get to unless you specifically search for it. If I search for something, I should get a little link at the top that more or less says "There are 30 old, closed questions that have been excluded from this search. [Include all closed questions]". Such questions should also disappear from all question lists (like the "highest votes" list). This cleanly avoids the broken windows problem. A visitor won't ever come across these, and neither will a regular user *unless they explicitly search for it*. Deleted questions sometimes have good answers. In other cases there are meta discussions about these. There are many times when I want to see a q on SO, and can't -- because the deletion army got there first. Giving them the silent treatment instead of deleting them avoids such annoyances, while still solving the broken windows problem.

I'm not entirely sure of this; but I'd like to put it out there :)

Comment: Deletion already is the silent treatment with a high rep bar for getting back to them. I think that serves more purpose than sweeping them under the rug. I don't think we really want people being able to dig them up even on Google. If there is good content, then the work should be put in to get them open.

Comment: @Caleb: The pages can always be `noindex` ed. It's just a closed  question. Whats wrong with letting others dig them up if they have to?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying that the delete button should be removed. Deletion should still be an option. However, the silent treatment seems like a saner option to me.

Comment: Just because you hide your broken windows in the back yard instead of the front doesn't change the fact that they are still lying around. What sort of questions are better off for being left to rot in the weeds rather than being taken to the dump or restored into presentability?

Comment: @Caleb: All of them. Other users may try to improve them. There's no "rot" going on here. The other day I needed to see a bunch of closed-then-deleted questions on EE as part of a meta discussion. There is a discussion on a specific question on MSO every day, and more often than not the question is deleted.

Comment: The broken windows thing says "don't leave bad stuff out in the open". We're not. The silent treatment is equivalent to deletion in terms of keeping content hidden. Your argument about rotting in the back yard can be applied to deletion as well (nothing is ever truly deleted). Just that the back yard has higher walls in this case.

Comment: You're basically describing two forms of deletion, Manishearth - "soft deletion" and "softer deletion". For the vast, *vast* majority of deleted questions, there's zero value in making them searchable; this would essentially be an [archive for those rare exceptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions/136261#136261) - which is a pretty major change to the system for a tiny, tiny minority of questions.

Comment: @shog true, which is why i'm unsure of this. However, to me it doesn't seem to be a major change -- it's just as major a change as the roomba. All that needs to be done is tweak the search and add noindex links to headers. There will not be any "softer deleted" state in the database(unlike the roomba which will flip the deleted column on for every post).

Comment: Deleting closed questions causes problems. In the case of manual deletions, it takes up time, and may lead to hasty deletes. In case of the roomba, we still have  a loose ends problem. Also, as Nicol says, "I have a general aversion to any automatic deletion of content". This proposal solves the broken windows problem, and elimimates the need for deletion of closed questions, and any problems that come with it, by replacing an active system with a passive one.

Comment: Basically, this eliminates the need for our current soft deletion system for closed questions (course, blatant crap can be deleted), and replaces it with a passive system that won't bother anyone andneeds no supervision. In my eyes, that's an improvement :/

Comment: @Manis: I'm not necessarily the best equipped to comment on this, but... From what I've seen, there are a *ton* of places in the code where the delete flag is checked in order to determine what to display and what not to. You're talking about adding *another* check to most/all of them. For, again, the tiny, *tiny* fraction of deleted posts that anyone actually cares about. Auto-deletion is reasonably simple - the functionality already exists and *already accounts for the bulk of deleted questions*; there's effectively no special handling for auto-deleted vs. mod-deleted.

Comment: @shog fair enough. I can't come up with anything more than: question lists, seaech, user page, tag page, but that's just me :s

Comment: I think Nicol's suggestion to hide *closed* posts in some of these scenarios would make more sense and cause considerably less confusion. As soon as there's another status, there needs to be some sort of indicator for it, and then we need to decide whether or not they make sense to show in related lists, auto-tweeted posts, feeds/newsletters/multicollider/anythingAPI, data dumps, 10k tools, review... I mean, think about it: *most of the site* is either displaying questions, or displaying links to questions.

Comment: @shog ... My suggestion is also to hide _closed_ questions from certain areas of the site. The only difference is  that I'm talking of 7d old posts, he's talking about all closed post; I'm talking about hiding it from search and certain question lists, he's only talking about the main page.

Comment: Yeah, but again: how many of these questions shouldn't just be deleted? You can *already* filter out closed questions from search results if you need to; I don't know that delisting them by default is a great idea - particularly if we're cleaning up the worst of them reasonably quickly. Re-reading your answer here, I'm still not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish - if it's hiding questions that are just noise, well... We should just delete them. If it's hiding questions that have some value but aren't generally acceptable for some reason, then: when/where *are* they acceptable?

Comment: @Shog9: My point was that Nicol's suggestion is more or less the same as mine, so I don't see how it makes more "sense". Regarding what I'm trying to accomplish: I'm just saying that deletion is rather unnecessary. It stops improvements from a large section of the community. It leaves loose ends/broken links on MSO and elsewhere (and we hate broken links, that's why we disallow link-only answers). There have been many times when a post is brought up on meta for discussion, and I can't see it since I don't have the rep.

Comment: Deletion causes a lot of whining as well. Finally, deletion is an active job -- someone has to do it (this is nullified by the roomba proposal though). I agree that there are only a few problematic deletions out of the vast majority of normal ones. However, if we can have a system (which I still feel is not too tough to make -- ne needn't hide old, closed questions from all q lists, only search, and the various lists on the main page) with very few _deletions_ and still solves the broken windows problem, then why should we let those few problematic deletions be there anyway?

Comment: Basically: Take a look at this from the point of view of _before_ we had a "delete closed questions policy". Doesn't this sound like a  saner option? Deletion is scary, and IMO unnecessary.

Comment: @Manishearth: please have a look through the results of the queries I posted, and see how many (or better yet, identify the defining characteristics of) the ones that you feel are worth keeping around *in any form*. What you're describing entails a non-trivial amount of effort; I'm not saying it's not worth implementing, but... It needs justification. "Deletion is scary" doesn't really provide that; most of these are really just noise, and we already have a perfectly good state (soft deletion) with which to remove clutter from the normal UI.

Comment: @Shog9: [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57216) is the first example I see on Phys (I'm not entirely familiar with the borders on good question/bad question on SO). It could be edited to remove it's agenda-pushingness and ask "what evidence do we have that the planck length [...]". I get what you mean, though :) I don't see how this is trivial if the question is made to disappear from only 3-4 lists (search, main page lists, Google `noindex`), but you know more than me about this.

Comment: Even that one hasn't been edited in over a week; somehow, I don't think hiding it is going to increase the chances of it being fixed up.

Comment: @Shog9: Hmm, true :s

Answer (score 5):

> - Closed, no answers, and no activity for at least a week (32K)
> - Closed, no up-voted/accepted answers and no pending reopen votes (61K)
> - Closed, no upvoted or accepted answers, scoring <= 0, no reopen votes, no edits since closed (48K)

I have a general aversion to any automatic deletion of *content*. That is, actual information that could be useful to someone. So if a closed question does have an answer, I think a human being needs to be involved in deciding whether it should go away.

Perhaps we should have tiers. The first tier is what you mention first: no answers, no activity for a week, and closed; such posts are *a priori* contentless (also, not closed as duplicates). The second tier is the second thing you mentioned, and it kicks in after, say, 3 weeks of inactivity with no pending reopen votes (ie: the answer(s) were never accepted or upvoted).

That should cover most of the cases, while still making sure that someone has given some minimal review to the utility of the content. That is, people saw it and didn't upvote anything.

---

We may want to consider not showing closed questions on the main page, unless they have been edited *since* they were closed. That will at least deal with the issue of "broken windows" on the main page.

---

If we allow users to see their deleted questions, we also need to make sure that users are informed that their question was deleted via an inbox message. Otherwise, how would they get such a link?

Comment: Moderators can ensure that users do get notified by leaving a comment prior to deletion. It *might* be worth expanding this functionality to comments from other users in some situations, but I don't think pinging someone about a question they've ignored for >= 1 week is going to help. I think making closed questions slightly less visible could be reasonable - not sure if the front page is that important, but tag pages and /questions might benefit.

Comment: @Shog9: "*I don't think pinging someone about a question they've ignored for >= 1 week is going to help.*" That would only be true if they never come back. Is automatically dropping them a note something *that* expensive that it needs to be avoided? People should know when they've had actions taken against their content. Even if it takes them a month or two to come back; if they drop in with a new question, they should see that their old one was rejected so that they don't do it again.

Comment: That's a more specific scenario, and I think makes for a better action item... Why not warn folks who go to post a question if their previous question(s) have been poorly-received? Forget deletion - if UserX's previous question was closed or heavily down-voted, give him a little reminder when he hits /questions/ask to the tune of, *"Your previous question, 'How do I shave my dog as a programmer?', was closed - please review it for guidance on avoiding such problems this time around."*

Comment: One way to get such links would be to add a new "Deleted" tab that appears only if the user has deleted (or recently deleted) questions. (Maybe it could also appear for users who posted answers to deleted questions to give them a chance to go in and salvage their content for possible later reuse.) Yes, it entails a mod of the user interface, but IMHO, it would improve things with regard to deleted questions.

Comment: I have to be honest, I'm not overly concerned about the ability of folks to find this stuff right now; in general, if they forget it exists that's just as well. In specific scenarios, it might be useful to give them a link - otherwise, it's more important that folks who still *have* a link are able to find out what happened. @RobH

Answer (score 2):

I really love the idea that the early deletion for 20k users can only apply to certain topics like

- Spam
- Hate-Speech
- ...

Kill that stuff immediately. (That is what early delete votes are for IMHO)

**But what shall be done with the other posts?**
Currently the early delete votes are used on VLQ so they don't have to come back 2 days later.

So I suggest, that you *can* vote to delete, but this vote will take effect until the 2 days are over.
In this time the OP or some other person can try to salvage the question.

**So what should happen with with the votes before the question was edited**

1. Discard the old votes?
2. Keep it and hope some people vote for *reopen, do not delete*?

I prefer the 2. way because this won't lead the OP from editing his question with `please don't delete it`.

So I suggest that you have to give a reason (multiple choice) to do a early deletion vote.
If the reason is not good enough for the early deletion, count it as "delete it later".

Answer (score -7):

*Danger, Will Robinson, Danger!*

It's very dangerous to get into more auto-deleting.  For now I'd just ask to **please make sure and exclude `Closed As Duplicates`**; let the stubs hangout and help searches.

Comment: I'll probably add more to this as I think on it.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more.

Comment: did you happen to look at as any of the queries I linked?

Comment: @Shog9, I hadn't before, thanks for thinking of this upfront.

Comment: The world is full of clear and present dangers. Sometimes the benefits outweigh the risks and action is called for. The risks can also be mitigated. There are also dangers in not acting. Are you sure you're not crying wolf before the wolf shows up -- perhaps even before you determine if they live in this forrest?

Comment: @Caleb, it's just a warning.  We've had huge problems with deletions in the past.

Comment: The problem is that they tend to *clog* searches, pushing away the legit results. [General Reference questions create low-quality dead ends for Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160565)

Comment: Not sure why people vote to delete because they disagree, but they definitely highlight the problem we have with deletions on these sites, Improper Usage.