# 10k users cannot see independently-deleted answers on their own deleted questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

The recent (fantastic) changes to deleted questions have introduced a bug. 10k users can no longer see answers to their deleted questions which were deleted before the question was deleted. That is to say: they cannot see answers which had their deletion flag set, rather than just inheriting it from their parent question.

The code that grants non-10k users the ability to see their own deleted questions but not independently-deleted answers appears to be applying to 10k users as well, even though in their case it's a restriction of privilege.

They are still able to edit the answer if they visit the edit page directly; this only affects the question view.

Comment: `The code that grants non-10k users the ability to see their own deleted questions` Wait, what? You can do this? How? I thought [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/180276) was [[meta-tag:status-declined]]...

Comment: @Doorknob I guess the question wasn't updated -- maybe because it refers to both questions and answers, but [the recent change they finally implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/134300) only affects questions.

Comment: @Doorknob, Jeremy: To be clear - anybody can see their own deleted answers as long as they have a link to the question which they answered. This has been the case forever. The change that was implemented applies to questions where sub-10k users would see a 404 page on their own deleted questions even if they visited the link directly - the links will display as deleted questions now instead of a 404 page. The request that was declined (and still is) specifically asks that the links to deleted content be displayed on the profile page, which is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The code that grants non-10k users the ability to see their own deleted questions but not independently-deleted answers appears to be applying to 10k users as well, even though in their case it's a restriction of privilege.

Yes. Oversight on my part - missed an extra Boolean test there. This issue was also affecting moderators and employees ;)

This is now fixed, and 10k users (as well as all other affected parties) can see all deleted posts again, on their own deleted questions and otherwise.