# Many posts removed at a time

Tags: support, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

I edit posts quite often and usually some of them are then removed and I lose the reputation gained by the edit. This is normal, and usually it happens to me with maybe 10% of edited posts in a day...

But some hours ago, my reputation fell down 20 points, because 10 posts that I had edited were removed at a time...

So, why were those posts removed? I guess there must be an automated process that deleted those posts, but with what criteria?

Comment: I suppose it would have been worse if the script had run shortly after you reached the 2000 threshold and make you lose the just-gained edit privilege again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The automatic deletion script ran about 5 hours ago. It removed questions that were downvoted and/or closed and received no other attention for 30 days.

You can find the current exact criteria [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/155160).

We are also looking at implementing [additional criteria for removing closed and abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/155160), but I don't think that's live yet.