# Users with less than 10K rep can add their own deleted question to favorites but can't see it listed

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, bookmarks

Now that users with less than 10K can [see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/152859), they can also add those questions to their favorites.

The action succeeds and the star toggles itself just fine showing the question is favorited, however it's not being added to the "favorites" tab.

I suggest one of the following to correct this behavior:

1. Let those users see their own deleted questions in the favorites list, with the special background same way like 10K+ users.
2. Don't let users with less than 10k reputation add deleted questions to favorites.

Comment: I think the fist one is more comfortable for users, which want to see/observe they own questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is far from ideal but as a workaround one could use [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) to display their bookmarks - since the Votes table includes the deleted posts. (For more details on this see: [The votes table doesn't have the votes for deleted posts, does it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354977)) In this way, one can get at least links to deleted questions among the bookmarks.

One caveat is that the database is updated only once a week - so you won't see the questions which were bookmarked very recently.

Here is a query [listing bookmarks of a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1538849/list-of-my-bookmarks?userid=183484) and also a bit [extended version of the same query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1538857/list-of-my-bookmarks-with-more-details-about-the-question?userid=183484).  (I have used myself as an example - but you can replace the userid by any user.)