# The votes table doesn't have the votes for deleted posts, does it?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, deleted-questions

Over the weekend I had a major mishap in my understanding what the Votes table in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer actually contains.

For the last 6 to 8 years I assumed [the schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677) only contains data for not deleted posts with a few exceptions, PostsWithDeleted and [PostLinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260676). So when Jon Ericson shared a [query that joined Votes and PostsWitdDeleted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1304928/votes-on-deleted-posts-by-year) I told him that couldn't be correct. I convinced myself being right because a slightly adapted [query by me](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1305012/votes-on-deleted-posts-by-year) showed way lower numbers. I did expect those to be zero, so I checked a few and all seemed to be related to roomba deletion, so I blamed the roomba script, put it to rest and called it a day.

On a revisit today I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1305863) and that taught me that there are way more votes for deleted posts still in the votes table than can be explained by a roomba issue:

[image]

The conclusion so far: the votes for deleted posts are somewhat in the Votes table after handchecking a good 30 posts.

What is the story of these Votes for deleted posts? Is this meant to be this way or is there something broken in the sanitizing script?

Comment: I'm going to look into this - it's on my to do list for hopefully today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the code that we use for the SEDE export and even double checked with [Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) to make sure the logic was correct.

Votes for deleted posts are included in the `Votes` table.

The only votes we exclude from the `Votes` table are those that have a deletion date and  have a `VoteTypeId` for a `follow`, everything else is fair game for querying. The specific `WHERE` clause is:

```
WHERE  DeletionDate IS NULL  
  AND  VoteTypeId <> 21
```

We do not exclude votes on posts that have been deleted.

Comment: This clears my misconception nicely. Now I can revisit all those posts where I said: That is not in the public schema ... ;)

Comment: Sweet, I created more work for you and not me. :P

Answer (score 10):

I've checked a couple of dozen posts on Chess Stack Exchange, and I can confirm almost all votes are there right now, even for deleted posts. The [few exceptions I found](https://data.stackexchange.com/chess/revision/1305946/1605616) are when an author deletes their own post (apparently, that doesn't count as a delete vote), when a moderator converts an answer to a comment (idem) and when a question deletion deletes the corresponding answers. None of them have up- or downvotes.

However, this has *always* (or at least a long, long time) been the case for spam and rude/abusive votes (yes, *votes*, not flags; they're stored as votes in the database). One of my earliest projects on Stack Exchange was the [Revision Downloader](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/tools/tree/master/revision-downloader), for downloading potentially spam or rude/abusive posts. It was based off of an existing SEDE query (no idea which one, and apparently I didn't know much about attribution back then) which queries votes/flags on deleted posts. That query is still correct; when I [run it now for Chess.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/chess/query/646101/deleted-spam-offensive-posts) it yields 68 results, which is *exactly* the number I get when I search for `deleted:1 locked:1 migrated:0`.

Comment: I was hand checking against SO. I didn't think of asking a mod of a smaller site and SEDE skills. Glad you could confirm it.