# Should not questions closed as off-topic on a meta site be a special case for deletion?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

As per recent changes, [a question that is closed cannot be deleted in the next two days from the closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/140449), if the question score is -2 or higher.
Considering that in a meta site like this one gets questions that should be asked on the main site, should not questions closed as off-topic on a meta site be an exception to the general rule?

Comment: What are the odds that such a question is -2 or higher at the time of closure?

Comment: It cannot be voted for deletion until the score is -3, or 2 days are passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 users who wish to vote to delete (as well as the other close voters) can always pile on downvotes. If there are upvotes, well, it may be a controversial post (there's a chance it shouldn't be deleted). In such cases, a mod can always delete it.

On MSO this is hardly a problem; OT posts get downvoted to about -6 before deletion. As far as I can tell, other metas don't have the problem either -- they get downvoted as well, though usually a mod gets to it first (since child metas ping the site mods for every new post).

So I don't see where this would be needed in practice. An OT question on meta is a quite rare use case (except on MSO, where they get dealt with well)