# Should this question have been deleted so quickly?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, new-users, moderation

[This new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326929/derek) just asked two (poor quality) questions about selecting a random image with PHP. The second was pretty much a duplicate of the first and the first, in its current state, deserved to be closed.

I thought I'd type a longer comment, with a fragment of code, to help a user who was evidently struggling. As is my usual practice I wrote a comment on on the second question, copied it to clipboard, and submitted it - only to find the question deleted. I surfed back to the user's first question (still in my browser history) to post it there, but found that deleted too.

My understanding of usual moderation policy is this is rather excessive deletion. Sure, the user shouldn't be posting duplicates immediately after a question close, but whilst it is fine to delete the duplicate (though unusual) it is excessive to delete the first one too - it might be rescued, or benefit from comments.

Normally reposted questions are left closed but visible, as it is useful to see this in the user's profile (if they are inclined to post duplicates directly against the advice of a close, that is useful for readers to know). Was the quick deletion right in this case?

Comment: Do you have links to the questions (from your browser history)? That way >10k users could see them as well (along with mods, who can see all deleted questions)

Comment: @DavidRobinson - [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639395/displaying-a-random-image-in-php), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639571/display-a-random-image-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, @Oded. halfer: Neither of those questions were deleted by a moderator, both were deleted by three users with the vote-to-delete privilege voting to delete after the question was closed.

Comment: I believe it's these: [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639395/displaying-a-random-image-in-php) and [the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639571/display-a-random-image-in-php).

Comment: @halfer - The comments from the user show that they are not interested in participating in the community. They are after an answer and are not willing to put effort into clarifying the question. This has caused the questions to be closed and then deleted fairly quickly by the community itself.

Comment: @David, thanks. I'm not _au fait_ with what permissions are required for deletion - so I didn't mean a diamond moderator as such - just that the questions were not self-deleted, and that it is not usual policy for poor on-topic questions to be deleted so quickly. Closed is fine, they weren't good questions. But deleted is unusual.

Comment: @Oded - I'm a frequent close-voter, but nevertheless maybe I am an optimist too, and wonder if occasionally help vampires can be saved. I think these should have remained closed but non-deleted, so that friendly people willing to engage briefly can do so if they choose.

Comment: The fact is, we don't have a way to enforce such a policy, even if it existed. I agree that it would be _nice_, but the OP has been obnoxious and vague enough to have been punished (and unfortunately question banned in the process - there are other deleted questions that you have not seen)

Comment: @halfer FYI, there were some [fairly recent changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/162704) to stop premature deletions. I can't see the deleted questions, but if they didn't meet the criteria that would prevent deletion for a couple of days (score >= -2), then... perhaps there wasn't any reason to keep them around at all?

Comment: -5 and -8 @Yannis, and a gimme teh codez with an actual "i dont care" thrown in...

Comment: @Yannis, certainly the questions were poor. But mine would have been the only friendly voice in a negative void, and _sometimes_ reaching out to the user can modify their behaviour. Unfortunately with both questions deleted, I have no way to offer that comment. Tbf, I don't see that the user was _obnoxious_, either.

Comment: @halfer Well, that's unfortunate, but... there are thousands of _other_ new users who could use your help, and some of them may deserve it a bit more?

Comment: @Yannis: my question is about policy, rather than just this user. I've been a member of SO for a few years, and _never_ seen an on-topic, closed question deleted so immediately.

Comment: @halfer I'm also (sort of) talking policy. Deleting unsalvageable posts quickly helps direct our collective focus to posts (and users) that are a bit more deserving of our time and energy. There's no policy _against_ speedy deletions, except the fairly recent changes I mentioned in an earlier comment. It's true that speedy deletions aren't very common (except in cases like spam), but they aren't forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

> Was the quick deletion right in this case?

I assume that the deletion of the question was the actual problem, and not *how fast* it actually happened.

The alternative to deletion was closing, but when closing questions, people could still answer it trough comments.

In case of duplicate question/answer it's right to delete the second one mainly because it's confusing when useful comments or answers are spread between two questions when they can easily be restricted to one (which is good for searching too).

> As is my usual practice I wrote a comment on on the second question [...] only to find the question deleted.

You should have expected that and commented only on the first one.

Comment: Actually the question is very clear: it's about the speed of the deletion, not the deletion itself. There's a reason why we don't let people cast delete votes on a new question unless it has < -2 net votes. It's to limit speedy deletion of things that could be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I agree that identical dups should be eventually deleted, though I frequently comment upon them to ask users not to repost questions that have been closed. So, there's value in being able to comment on a dup (even if the life of those comments is brief before the question is zapped). As for commenting on the first question; as I say I tried that, and that one was deleted too - which was rather quick for a new question.