# Why can I delete some questions, but not others (at >20k rep)

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-delete

I've noticed with increasing frequency that there are some closed questions that I cannot delete (as in, there is no "Delete" link):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760317/what-is-the-first-language-that-implements-the-c-sharp-attribute-like-feature
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758778/gis-web-aplication
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760486/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-vb-databasequer-write

Whereas I *can* delete these recently closed questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760146/how-to-count-number-of-bytes-sent-received-by-a-process
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760459/algorithm-for-celebrity

I am unable to determine what the criteria are for whether I can (vote-to-) delete the question.  My understanding was that as a "Trusted User" I can delete even new questions (though the examples above are all new).

Does anyone know why I can delete some but not others?

Comment: You can no longer immediately vote to delete questions that are -2 or higher. This change is mentioned somewhere but I don't have a link handy.

Comment: Ah! I missed it on the Recent Changes page, but now I see it on 4-23-2013.  Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, all but one of the questions you linked to will eventually be deleted automatically. Please reserve your delete votes for stuff that the system can't clean up automatically (or is so blatantly inappropriate that it must be removed quickly).

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for the tip.  I didn't realize questions were ever automatically deleted. Is there anything written up on that?

Comment: Sure - [here's what's in place now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), while [this will be active soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675).