# Is there any reason we shouldn't let posters self-delete closed questions immediately?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

It's been brought to my attention that since the [new deletion changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/147336) rolled out, there's a seeming inconsistency when you want to delete your own (non-negative-scored) question

- You **can** always delete your own, unanswered, *open* question, but
- You **cannot** delete your own, unanswered *closed* question for two days after closure

This seems illogical; if anything, others having closed a question would seem to make it a better candidate for self-deletion, not worse.  And given that one of the window's main goal is to ensure the OP has a chance to clarify or improve, I don't see much point in blocking it.

Am I missing anything obvious?

EDIT: It appears that this issue pre-dates the changes - before, the same seeming inconsistency existed for users without deletion privileges; now it exists for everyone.  Also, I stink at finding dupes.

Comment: This seems like a logic trip up to me, I guess the roomba changes overrode the self-delete feature.

Comment: When people flag their own closed questions for deletion, I delete them 100% of the time, unless it was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It appears that I failed to find ANY of the dupes of this.  Self-closing.

Comment: It is the kind of logic singularity you get when 5 high-rep users cannot delete a question while one no-rep user can.

Answer (score 8):

### Nope.

In fact, it makes no sense to keep it this way. Think about it - if I, the OP, genuinely want to delete a post for *any reason*, does that say anything about its chances of being reopened? They're slim to none.

Comment: +1 (While your latest edit is much more constructive, your original body gave me a good laugh.)

Comment: @Jaydles All I needed was the first word!

Comment: For those who can't see it, it was a big 'nope' with the words '*While you're at it, get rid of this quality filter.*'