# Disallow VLQ flags on "on hold" questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, low-quality-posts, on-hold

If a question is "on hold" - basically telling the user to improve it - there is little to no reason to flag it as VLQ. So I suggest to disallow this flag type on closed questions.

If a question really needs moderator deletion it can be flagged with a custom reason stating why it should be obliterated. Otherwise people with enough rep can simply vote to delete it later.

Comment: Yes, please. Almost all of these flags are useless in light of the [accelerated question deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/135615) process for bad closed questions. These don't require moderator attention, and frankly many of them look like they're from people hoping to farm helpful flags for badges and the like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a bug that was showing the VLQ option on on-hold/closed questions - a fix will be pushed out shortly.