# How to see list or history of all deleted answer on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I am curious to know if any way exist to see my deleted history like favorites. I did not found any related answer. One more thing, I talked about all history. I can see one at a time if I browse  the question but no one will remember all link which had been deleted.

Comment: No, that's the whole point of deleting something: to remove it.

Comment: Yes i do agree with your points. But we can learn from our mistakes by seeing it. And sometimes some post may useful

Comment: No way through Stack Overflow itself. Feel free to maintain external list of your answers so the links won't be lost but other then that, only moderators can see this in your profile.

Comment: The only thing that makes any sense to me is showing you a list of your *own* deleted answers. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about here. Your comment talks about learning from your mistakes, but the question indicates otherwise. Anyway, [that's already been suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) (and declined).

Comment: The answer is in the FAQ, under "Can I see a list of my deleted posts?".

Comment: Could anyone with >=10k rep. please see the deleted answer of mine, which was answered on off-topic question about Spring vs. Spring MVC vs. Spring Boot? I just want to copy that text for one of my mates.. I forgot to save the link to that deleted answer..

Answer (score 1):

Once you gain 10,000 rep, you will gain access to the [Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). This is when you will be able to see all deleted posts. They keep this bar very high to prevent people inexperienced with the SE network to view content that shouldn't be viewed.

[A change was recently made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675) that allows you to view your own deleted questions and answers, as long as you have a link to them.

And as Cody Gray said, the [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) to have deleted questions and answers still appear in your profile has been declined