# One of my questions was recently "removed" and I don't know why

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I was wondering this morning why I was 3 rep less and then I tracked it down to this recent activity:

```
-3  10 hours ago    removed     Using Kendo upload to extract txt file data and record to a database
```

There was no downvote or any explanation provided, just that the question was "removed". Not only did I lose the reputation I had earned from this question, but last I remember, I was still interested in an answer for future reference.

Can someone please explain what happened and why my question was deleted?

Comment: The Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363560/using-kendo-upload-to-extract-txt-file-data-and-record-to-a-database

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that - you got eaten by the roomba because of age, low views and a zero net score.

Answer (score 2):

[A question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363560/using-kendo-upload-to-extract-txt-file-data-and-record-to-a-database) got removed. You got 1 upvote and 1 downvote (5 - 2 = 3). That score got removed along the deletion.

[image: screenshot]

Your question got deleted [automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/172011).

Comment: As for **why** it got deleted - part 3 of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion

Comment: @Oded is there anyway to get it un-deleted then as I'd still like an answer to it plus every little bit of rep at my level helps.

Comment: @Myzifer - Why? It didn't get any attention and there is little to believe that it would now. Ask a new question - make it as detailed as possible. Follow the guidelines here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @Oded There is always the chance that someone would search for a related topic and find that question and know an answer.  That's at least the most likely scenario but I still don't see why I can't have the question closest 1st allowing me to remake the question and see what might of been useful or not.

Comment: @Oded he did mentioned that he had an interesting answer which he wants to refer now, he should have upvoted that answer in first case

Comment: @CRUSADER - there are no answers on that question. If there were, the automated process wouldn't have deleted it.

Comment: @CRUSADER I said I'm still interested in an answer as it's an issue which could come up again in the future and I'd like an answer to it, if it did come up again and I had the spare rep I'd stick a bounty on it if I wasn't able to find or come up with a solution at that time.

Comment: @Oded So can I please get my question un-deleted as it's still a topic I'd like an answer on even if I have to wait a while.

Comment: @Myzifer - I can undelete it. But the automatic system will delete it tomorrow. Write a new question - update it with as much detail as possible. Follow the guidelines I linked to. If needed, post a bounty on it.

Comment: @Oded I'd need the old question as reference to even hope to figure out what possible way to improve it if possible otherwise I could end up writing the exact same question in near enough the same detail and without any feedback to know whats right or wrong.  If you un-delete it for a day then I can at least try and see if I can either get some extra activity on it or as mentioned use it as reference. Plus it was unvoted so it seems I'm not the only one interested in finding a solution to this particular issue.

Comment: @Myzifer - You have a link to it. Several times here. You can see it even though it is deleted. What's the problem again?

Comment: @Oded all the links I'd opened were to the roomba topic and I'd missed the original post, I see now tho that it was also closed as not a real question but no feedback given as to exactly why this was.  Additionally now that I've been able to read that question I can see that I did recreate the question when it was closed with little changed and got an answer.  I'm still not happy about losing the rep I earned from that question as it's not transferred over to the new question.

Comment: @Myzifer - consider that it may garner more downvotes. A good question will get you more reputation on the first upvote. Let it go and move on.

Comment: Are you really complaining about losing a grand total of 3 points? Seriously? Post *one* decent answer to a question, and you'll gain at least +10. @myz

Comment: @Oded It's a closest question to which someone found useful and none of the people who wanted it closest even bothered to say what was wrong with it. I do like to improve but if I'm not given any feedback then there really isn't much chance of that happening.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes cody when that's close to 1/100th of my total rep and I'm so low rep compared to some then every little bit counts, especially when you lose all your bounty rep even without an answer.

Comment: Heck now I can complain about someone serial downvoting me.

Comment: @CodyGray Rather interesting cody that I got 4 downvotes and you have -4 rep so care to explain?

Comment: @Myzifer Someone is serially downvoting both of our posts?