# Is the Roomba broken?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, auto-delete

I know that there is a system for auto-deletion of certain closed and unanswered questions, as described by Shog9 in ["Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675), but it was my understanding this only acted on closed questions.

This morning, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872046/php-source-code-in-utf-8-files-how-to-interpret-properly) was automatically deleted by the system as part of the automatic question removal script. It doesn't seem to fit the qualifications laid out by Shog9 in the above answer, as it was never closed, merely downvoted once.

Is there a bug in the auto-deletion routine? If so, have other downvoted but not closed questions been accidentally deleted in this manner?

Comment: "If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...

- has −1 or lower score - has no answers - is not locked

...or...

it was closed and migrated to a different site

... it will be automatically deleted."

Comment: @animuson - For reference, you're talking about the FAQ answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006 . Huh, I had no idea that downvoted, unanswered, but not closed questions were automatically deleted by the system. I was somehow under the impression that this only applied to closed questions. I'll close this and point to the FAQ. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, we did end up with the notion of "abandoned questions", above and beyond "abandoned _closed_ questions".

Comment: Roomba needs sleep too.