# Don't award the Tumbleweed badge if I delete my question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, deleted-questions, tumbleweed-badge

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ask a question
2. Delete your question
3. One week later
4. Un-delete your question
5. ???
6. Get Tumbleweed badge!

Personally, I think that the system shouldn't award the badge in cases like these.

Thoughts?

Comment: While I'm inclined to agree; the tumbleweed badge is a consolation prize anyway. If people want it that badly then fair enough

Comment: @RichardTingle did all `293.3k` users want it *that bad*? hehe. It's a bug/fault in the system and it should have been fixed. Thanks Dave Chen for pointing it out

Comment: Agreed. It's an overlook of the [Roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513/152859) that allowed users to see their own deleted questions regardless of their reputation. :)

Comment: @mehow Did all 293.3k users ask a question, delete it, wait a week, undelete it, then `???`? Most likely not. Without knowing how many were legitimate badge awards, we can't really comment on the impact of this fault, but, at worst, we're awarding way too many badges, which are rather pointless already, not to mention that Tumbleweed is bronze. Most of us have more than enough bronze badges already.

Comment: I guess the Tumbleweed badge condition should include a "Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week, *being active all this time*"

Comment: "Steps to reproduce" do you think anyone will try to reproduce it? :P

Comment: Tumbleweed is for questions that aren't exactly bad, but don't attract attention, right? For me question kept deleted only to be undeleted later meets that description pretty well.

Comment: @Mołot Bad questions can still be deleted by their owner, only to be undeleted a week later though.

Comment: @DaveChen I was under impression they would be downvoted fairly quickly and that would be hard to post bad stuff and delete it before downvotes happen. I admit it's only my impression not backed up by facts, so you may have a point here.

Comment: You can post and delete before anyone even sees the question. I mean you can just click on delete right after you've posted. How could anyone get in between to downvote?

Comment: @Dukeling note that the delete/undelete your own question is relatively new to site so i doubt anyones used the OP's described technique to actually get the badge. my point was it is a bug and needs to be fixed that's it

Comment: @mehow I don't argue that it's a bug, my point is that this should be one of **the** lowest priority requests on here, so I'd rather have the devs spend time on more significant bugs / feature requests ... even if this would take like an hour to fix.

Comment: @Dukeling yeah i see your point. since it's been now exposed to the community the actions should take place before people start to abuse and exploit it, and trust me the SO developers get things done really quickly if needed!

Comment: Ooh, thanks. Tumbleweed badge, here I come! :P

Comment: OMG nice it worked :) Usually if I ask C# questions they will never get Tumbleweeded lol

Comment: We solved this problem by [retiring the badge altogether](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/).

Comment: @JonEricson: Well, I suppose that's *one* way to fix a bug.