# Fix verbiage about deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

In the Help Center->Answering section it says:

> **What happens when a post is deleted?**
>   Once a post has been deleted, it
>   will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users
>   with over 10,000 reputation. However, deleted posts can be undeleted
>   by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will
>   no longer be deleted.

Since we now [allow users to see their own deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/13295), that should be noted in the paragraph.

Comment: This is already mentioned in the section for [deleted questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions): "Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors." Strange why it doesn't say the same for [deleted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), since users have always been able to see their own deleted answers (even before the change you mention, which pertains only to questions).

Comment: Hmmm, it actually applies to more than self-deletion (though not very functional if not self-deleted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The articles about both deleted questions and deleted answers have been updated to specify that these types of posts are always visible to their original authors.