# Question of mine disappeared

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1502148/gabor-bakos) is my profile on Stack Overflow. As I remember recently I had two questions. One about PlayN (still there) and one about sbt-osgi (how can I set a target platform). There were somebody who downvoted both recently (I just guess it is a single person, not two individual visitors of the question within 2 minutes.) Although it seems the question about sbt-osgi is gone.

Do you have an idea what happen to it? (I do not remember deleting it, cannot see it in the [recently deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1502148) section either.) I have deleted one of my answers recently for a duplicate question, I was unsatisfied with my answer. Could it be related?
Thanks

Comment: [Auto deleted by community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470410/specifying-target-platform-in-sbt) there's some cleanup process that automatically removes negatively voted questions without answers. Can't find the exact criteria now.

Comment: The confusing thing about "recent deleted" is that the recent refers to when the post was posted rather than when it was deleted

Comment: @MartinSmith do you mean criteria listed in [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773)?

Comment: @gnat - Yes. That's it!

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, I was unaware of this process, that explains. It would be nice to be able find it somewhere in my profile though.