# Why downvoting on questions that are sure to get close or flagged

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

I was always curious about what is the sense in downvoting on a question in following case:

1. The OP has 1 rep and the question is clearly a spam or off-topic, generally  a question to be flagged/closed.

In this case isn't it more efficient to flag the question or if able to cast for closing?

Comment: Downvotes also count towards question ban, so the system can automatically stop people who repeatedly ask bad questions.

Comment: Plus it's a _good sign_ for the OP to understand that there is something wrong with the question.

Comment: I don't think people *should* be downvoting spam. That's what the spam flag is for. If too many people downvote a spam post then it'll disappear off the front screen and therefore may stick around longer than it should do.

Comment: Just so you readers understand what @JonW said, let me say it again: **Don't downvote spam.** Flag it and move on. The flag carries an automatic downvote by itself.

Comment: Don't downvote spam, but for other kinds of "sure to get closed" questions, downvote if they're bad to help the [Roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513/162102) clean them up later.

Comment: @JonW - Downvoting spam is fine *if* they are flagging it as well. Since the post is removed as soon as it receives 6 flags.

Comment: @hims056 no, I disagree. Downvoting means it'll fall out of view on the front page so may not even get get 6 spam flags it needs to be removed. Downvoting spam is therefore both useless *and* incorrect.

Comment: @JonW - How many downvotes requires to fall out of view on the front page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are too many reasons. Some of them are:

1. It discourages people including the OP to do the same in future.
2. Downvoted post indicates that the post is poor and needs some attention so usually people check downvoted post first. So such posts get enough flags/votes faster.
3. As @3ventic's Shadow said 20k users can vote to delete faster.
4. And yeah it *helps* the OP to get post ban.

Comment: Don't forget that highly downvoted questions don't appear on the front page anymore.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe - Yeah true. But mostly one who downvotes also flags the post and it only requires [6 flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/187824) to delete the spam post. So downvoting and flagging spam post is fine.

Answer (score 17):

A question needs to have -3 score to allow 20k users to immediately after closing to vote to delete the question. Downvotes also affect question bans and hide the question from the front page.

Comment: Didn't know that