# What is the privilege outcome of merging two accounts?

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

If I merge two accounts, what is outcome of posting privileges? One account does not have question asking permission, the other does.

What should be expected if I merge?

Comment: That depends on the direction of the merge. If you were trying to avoid a question ban by creating a new account, then that new account will be merged back into the account with the ban and the ban will remain in place.

Comment: If this - http://stackoverflow.com/users/2654498/nicholas-v - is your second account on SO, come clean now and get the accounts merged

Comment: @ChrisF, definitely my account, nothing I'm trying to hide here. Long time ago I posted on *this* account, without the expected question asking details... I understand perfectly on that account now, and I feel i'm functioning well. I have no problem with merging them... Hopefully getting question permission back is eventually a possibility?

Comment: How do you not have question asking permission? The account ChrisF linked isn't suspended.

Comment: You mean you have a post-ban? Then surely you've seen the message that comes with that, as well as the link with all the info you need?

Comment: @NicholasVielbig - you need to improve your existing questions so that they get up votes.

Comment: @Ataraxia I believe this account that I am on currently, is banned on SO from question asking.

Comment: @Ataraxia - this account - http://stackoverflow.com/users/2287328/nicholas-vielbig - is blocked from asking questions.

Comment: @ChrisF - giving good answers to other questions can also help.

Comment: @Oded - indeed. I should have mentioned that as well.

Comment: @Ataraxia , yes. That's this account. I believe it's a SO specific restriction.

Comment: If it did it I believe it would indicate that you're suspended and for how long. And your rep would be locked at 1.

Comment: @Ataraxia Timed suspensions and post-bans are different things. Post-bans are not indicated in the profile and the reputation is not set to 1.

Comment: Ah ok. I think this is relevant then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers. It explains why post bans happen and how you can prevent them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information. I was **that guy** (this account) in terms of question asking originally because I was new with SE in general. I have a good understanding of forum etiquette now, and was just looking to merge the to avoid the annoying auto logging into both accounts that is occurring. If I did merge them, and question restrictions were still present, I will be happy to improve my existing questions that caused all of this to begin with. Sorry about the novice beginning that I had with the forum on this account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first off: if we *catch* you running multiple accounts to work around posting restrictions (of any sort - suspensions, rate-limits, quality-bans), you'll end up suspended and unable to post or edit *anything*. Generally, this happens becomes someone complains (re-posting the same poorly-written question on several different accounts is kind of a dead giveaway), but there are all sorts of stupid things that happen to bring this up. See: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685)

If you request the merge yourself, the results depend on the state of *both* accounts - it's effectively the same as if you had just used one account from the start, with rate-limits, quality-checks and suspensions in effect based on the combined histories of both.

Comment: so, yeah. I have two accounts (Nicholas V. and Nicholas Vielbig), and I didn't mean to violate all these rules by doing so. If merging the two restricts the resulting account until I improve my previous question quality, that is definitely fine with me. I am just honestly annoyed by having two accounts and not knowing which I am logged into when, etc.

Comment: Ok - [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) & we'll get you squared away.