# Automatic quality control and their effects on participation and contribution

Tags: discussion, question-quality, quality-filter, answer-quality

I am interested in studying how automatic quality control can affect participation and contribution in online discussion communities. Many content generation platforms are struggling with balancing the quality of participation with the openness to all members.

I looked up several discussions on Stack Exchange, and it seems that the site implemented automated quality filters in 2017. I also noticed the debate about the potential outcomes of these filters.

I am wondering if more information about the implementation of these filters is available for a systematic inquiry into this question. In particular:

- Were they introduced for the first time in 2017, is there an exact date?
- Were they introduced in all stacks? Are dates of new feature implementation available?
- Do they apply to all users or just users with a certain reputation threshold?

Some relevant discussions:

[Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system)

[How does Stack Exchange attempt to prevent low-quality questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-exchange-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers/84670#84670)

[What will be the impact of the new filters on non-English speakers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91006/what-will-be-the-impact-of-the-new-filters-on-non-english-speakers)